# How can I change the default audio device from command line?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Ubuntu's desktop gui is great for changing audio settings (System->Preferences->Sound), like the default input/output device and setting the volume.

However, I would like to be able to do these things from the command-line. What tool is the gui using behind the scenes?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You can control PulseAudio thoroughly through the command line using `pacmd` and `pactl` commands. For options see `pacmd --help` or the wiki at [PulseAudio](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/CLI):

`pacmd list-sinks` for name or index number of possible sinks

`pacmd list-sources` for name or index number of possible sources

`pacmd set-default-sink "SINKNAME" | index` to set the default output sink

`pacmd set-default-source "SOURCENAME" | index` to set the default input

`pacmd set-sink-volume index volume`

`pacmd set-source-volume index volume` for volume control (`65536` = 100 %, `0` = mute; or a bit more intuitive `0x10000` = 100 %, `0x7500` = 75 %, `0x0` = 0 %)

and many many more CLI options.

---

**Note:** Changing the output sink through the command line interface can only take effect if [stream target device reading](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/DefaultDevice/) is disabled. This can be done by editing the corresponding line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to:

```
load-module module-stream-restore restore_device=false
```

Restart PulseAudio for changes to take effect:

`pulseaudio -k`

---

For a more elaborate tutorial on how to do this, and for instructions on how to change the sink during playback [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/72076/3940).

Comment: Pulseaudio has changed, the first command now should be `pacmd list-sinks` I think

Comment: How would one go about setting an output device to the default input device?  I have a Line6 ToneportUX1 (used for moulding guitar tones) that shows up as an output device in Ubuntu's sound control panel, but it should be an input device.

Comment: @MikeDtrick: this can't be done with these commands. I have no experience with USB devices, but I believe it may be a profile/driver/port/ALSA issue you may have. Is the device recognized as input in ALSA?

Comment: I've just started using AlsaMixer, so I'm probably not going to be much help.  Under `/proc/asound/cards/` it lists the Toneport as a USB device and under `/proc/asound/pcm` it says `playback 1: capture 1`.  This is all after running `alsamixer` and clicking [f2].

Comment: If your `pacmd list-sinks` lists only one sink but you can see several output devices in System Settings > Sound, check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63599/configuring-hdmi-audio-via-command-line

Comment: The page behind the link "stream target device reading" is now at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/DefaultDevice/

Comment: @scai; great! Thanks for this. I edited my answer for the new link.

Comment: I couldn't switch from headphone to HDMI output this way. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/898638/349837) is how I solved it.

Comment: See also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Set_default_input_sources where I found something very useful: how to find the right source and make it default ALL time time, through reboots, without running any commands or GUI every again.

Comment: can also do `pactl list short sinks` for a simpler list of sinks. You need the symbolic name.

Comment: @TimRichardson thank you for that suggestion - this was not yet possible in 2010 (when I wrote that answer).

Comment: PulseAudio has added another hoop to jump through: you must change the stream-restore module in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to read `load-module module-stream-restore restore_device=false`.  If you do not, then PulseAudio will ignore the default sink for any program you have used before (even if it is no longer running). PulseAudio is trying to be clever and now treats the default sink as only a  "fallback", to only be used if it doesn't know better. And, PulseAudio *always* seems to knows better.

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: If it wasn't immediately obvious, the sink index can be used in place of "SINKNAME". Thank you for your answer!

Comment: This is how I changed to **HDMI** `pacmd set-default-sink $(pactl list short sinks | grep hdmi | awk '{print $2}') && pulseaudio -k`

Comment: sink = output (speaker)
source = input (microphone)

Answer (score 11):

Yes there is type **alsamixer** in terminal

[image]

Press ,

> F1 - Help
>
> F2 - System Information
>
> F6 - Select Sound Card
>
> Esc - Exit the menu

Comment: alamixer seems good for changing the volume.  How do I change the default device?

Comment: I use it only for adjusting volume levels.Try pressing F6 key and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: F6 lets you choose a sound card to manipulate, but it doesn't change the default.

Comment: While it's useful (essential) to know about alsamixer, it does not answer OP's question whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

I found these instructions to be clear and easy to follow. It explains how to set the default audio output device (speakers, etc), from the command line, as well as how to make your chosen setting the system default, so that it is set after the machine is rebooted.

> Set the default output sink
>
> To list the output sinks available, type the following command:
>
> $ pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index:'
>
> - index: 0
>
>   name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_04_01.0.analog-stereo>
>
>   index: 1
>
>   name:  <combined>
>
> The * in front of the index indicates the current default output.
>
> To set a system wide default, add the source name in the default.pa file:
>
> /etc/pulse/default.pa
>
> ...
>
> set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_04_01.0.analog-stereo
>
> ...
>
> When done then you can logout/login or restart PulseAudio manually for these changes to take effect.

from [Set the default output sink](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Set_the_default_output_sink)

Answer (score 4):

```
pavucontrol
```

Not the actual Ubuntu volume control, but better! It lets you control default devices, and even devices per application/stream.

You have to have the app actually be recording/playing for it to appear in the 'Playback' or 'Recording' tabs, but once you choose the device for that app, it seems to remember it forever.

Also, (on a side note), for old (non pulse) applications, run them after `padsp`, eg:

```
padsp some_old_app
```

[image: pavucontrol]

Comment: The question is how to change the audio device from the command line. This is not an application for the command line.

Comment: also, `pavucontrol` is showing only connected devices, not the paired but disconnected ones.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of WirePlumber (a PipeWire session manager), `wpctl` can help you.

Get the available audio devices with `wpctl status` (default is shown with a `*`):

```
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [0.3.77, machitgarha@machitgarha, cookie:2827478639]
 └─ Clients:
...

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      46. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │      78. Headset H390                        [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *   49. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 0.90]
 │      84. Headset H390 Pro                    [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │...

...
```

Extract the number of the device from the "Sinks" section, and change the default audio sink (i.e. device) using `wpctl set-default`. For example, to change it to "Headset H390 Pro":

```bash
wpctl set-default 84
```

Check if the default sink is changed with `wpctl status`.