# Does HDMI require X in order to display?

Tags: server, xorg, hdmi

I'm working with a user on a different question and I am beginning to wonder if I might be barking up the wrong tree. The original question deals with setting a script to run XMBC when the HDMI cable is plugged in to the server. However, there is no output to the HDMI when connected. Which leads me right back to the original question:

Does HDMI require X in order to function?

Here's the original [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548041/run-process-when-hdmi-port-active-cec/548046?noredirect=1#comment750992_548046)

Comment: I don't think it does. My monitor, connected to my laptop, shows the boot sequence and logo fine, connected with HDMI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. All that is required is proper video output data, provided via the display adapter; the same as with VGA, DVI, or DisplayPort, as well as HDMI.