# Run script when monitor is connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, scripts, xrandr, udev, events

I am trying to run a script located in `usr/local/bin/` when I connect an external monitor to my laptop. I have tried to add a new `udev` rule but that did not work. I created a new file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` called `vga-monitor-connect.rules`. The contents of the file were

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/panel-fix"
```

I took the line from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/270574/399217)

After searching online I also tried the following rule

```
KERNEL=="card0", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/rumesh/.Xauthority", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/panel-fix"
```

However this didn't work either.

I have run the script manually and I can confirm that it works so it is not a problem with my script.

I also want to make it clear that I do not know much about `udev` so the rule I have used may be wrong. If anyone knows the proper rule for my problem please leave an answer.

My graphics card is an Intel GM965 integrated chipset

Comment: Do you specifically want to do it like this? A tiny background script would be a piece of cake.

Comment: @JacobVlijm How would the script be? Could you show an example.

Comment: Is it only to trigger if (any) second monitor is attached?

Comment: Yes I need to run my own script when I attach the second monitor

Comment: I will get back in a few hours if not solved yet, I am not on my own system :)

Comment: No problem, take your time and answer when you can :)

Comment: Added the answer. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### An alternative way to run a command if a screen is connected or disconnected

An alternative solution would be to run a tiny background script. Running the script below in the background, I could not measure any increase in processor load whatsoever.

It is an easy an convenient way to run a script, or any other command, whenever a second screen is connected or disconnected.

#### The example script

- Simply checks every five seconds how many times the string " connected " occurs in the output of the command `xrandr` (mind the space after "connected" to prevent false matches with "disconnected"). Each occurrence represents a connected screen.
- If the number of occurrences changes, either a screen was connected or disconnected. The change is "noticed" by the script and can be connected to a command, you can set in the head section of the script.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

#--- set both commands (connect / disconnect) below
connect_command = "gedit"
disconnect_command = ""
#---

def get(cmd): return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
# - to count the occurrenc of " connected "
def count_screens(xr): return xr.count(" connected ")
# - to run the connect / disconnect command(s)
def run_command(cmd): subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])

# first count
xr1 = None

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    # second count
    xr2 = count_screens(get(["xrandr"]))
    # check if there is a change in the screen state
    if xr2 != xr1:
        print("change")
        if xr2 == 2:

            # command to run if connected (two screens)
            run_command(connect_command)
        elif xr2 == 1:
            # command to run if disconnected (one screen)
            # uncomment run_command(disconnect_command) to enable, then also comment out pass
            pass
            # run_command(disconnect_command)
    # set the second count as initial state for the next loop
    xr1 = xr2
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `connect_screen.py`
2. In the head section, set the command to run on connect ( I set "gedit" as an example, mind the quotes). Also it is possible to set a command on disconnect, likewise. Else leave `disconnect_command = ""` as it is.

   *If* you do use a disconnect- command, also uncomment the line:

   ```
   run_command(disconnect_command)
   ```

   and comment out the line:

   ```
   pass
   ```

   As indicated in the script
3. Test-run the script from a terminal, connect your screen and see if all works fine.
4. If all works fine, add it to your startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15&&python3 /path/to/connect_screen.py"
   ```

   The `sleep 15` is to make the desktop start up completely before the script starts to run. Just to make sure.

---

#### EDIT

#### How to run the script on start up in a "smart" way.

The break of `sleep 15` should work in general, but since the start up time differs per system, It might take some experimenting to find the right break time. With a small addition, the script becomes "smart", and waits for the `xrandr` command to be successful before it starts the actual script. If you use the version below, you only need to add the command:

```
python3 /path/to/connect_screen.py
```

to your Startup Applications. Further usage is exactly the same as the version above.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

#--- set both commands (connect / disconnect) below
connect_command = "gedit"
disconnect_command = ""
#---

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(["xrandr"])
    except:
        pass
    else:
        break


# function to get the output of xrandr
def get(cmd): return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
# - to count the occurrenc of " connected "
def count_screens(xr): return xr.count(" connected ")
# - to run the connect / disconnect command(s)
def run_command(cmd): subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])

# first count
xr1 = None

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    # second count
    xr2 = count_screens(get(["xrandr"]))
    # check if there is a change in the screen state
    if xr2 != xr1:
        if xr2 == 2:
            # command to run if connected (two screens)
            run_command(connect_command)
        elif xr2 == 1:
            # command to run if disconnected (one screen)
            # uncomment run_command(disconnect_command) to enable, then also comment out pass
            pass
            # run_command(disconnect_command)
    # set the second count as initial state for the next loop
    xr1 = xr2
```

Comment: You are giving a bicycle to a man with a broken fast car instead of fixing the car...

Comment: @solsTiCe 1. This is no bicycle, but a perfectly functional option. Keep in mind that *all* notify-, event- or whatever driven actions exist of running some kind of a loop somehow. 2. I suggest you fix the Ferrari then.

Comment: @Rumesh Perfect! Glad it works.

Comment: @JacobVlijm the command to run the script at starup does not work, I used `python3 /usr/local/bin/connect_screen.py` instead. I suggest you edit the answer so that other people do not have trouble getting the script to run on startup

Comment: @Rumesh running scripts in `$PATH` *with* file extension, and *with* preceding language is a not-so-elegant solution. The question is if you want to run it for one user or for all users. In the last case, another setup than the suggested is needed, but preferably not the one you are suggesting :). The `sleep 15` might not be sufficient, but a more elegant solution could be to make the break "smart", let the script try/except to start up until the startup procedure is "ready" for the script to run. WOuld be a minor addition. Let me know.

Comment: @Rumesh scripts in `$PATH` should not have language extension and be executable, so run without `python3` see https://lintian.debian.org/tags/script-with-language-extension.html

Comment: I only have one user on my of so I only need the script for one user. What command do you want me to try? I'll do it and tell you the result

Comment: @JacobVlijm it be better to make another script and run the Python script from that? It would avoid the file extension and the sleep command may also be used properly

Comment: @Rumesh is the script only for personal use (locally)? No need for an extra script, I can make this one "wait" for the desktop to be fully loaded. As a background information: for an executable to work, the language extension plays no role at all, you can leave it away if you want (but then also the command to run it would change :) ) Only for importing the language extension is important. see http://askubuntu.com/a/590416/72216

Comment: @JacobVlijm script is only needed locally. Ok I'll try to just use the script name and let you know how it works out

Comment: @Rumesh Nono, that was just as information, it won't change a thing :) I'll make another version.

Comment: @JacobVlijm well I just tried with `conect_screen` and it works. but I had to mark it as executable with `chmod +x` first.

Comment: @Rumesh ??? That is odd, since it won't change anything to the timing. Let me know if it only succeeded incidentally, than Iĺl make an edited version :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I dont really understand the need to use `sleep` anyway, dont the commands just run when the user has logged in?

Comment: @Rumesh In some cases, commands break if the GUI is not completely finished loading if the script starts. This is often the case with touchpad related commands, many things concerning external screens, (sometimes) loading indicators etc. Then building in a break befaore the script actually starts helps. Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/609490/running-a-script-at-startup-that-uses-xrandr-to-set-display-options/609499#609499 It only worked after a time out of 100 seconds :) (see futher below in the comments). I am pretty sure that is the case in your situation as well.

Comment: @Rumesh See my edited answer. This should end all startup issues :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm The old script worked fine when I put `connect_screen` in the startup applications, Ill edit the script to the new one you put up but should I put `python3 /usr/local/bin/connect_screen.py` or just `connect_screen`. I am asking because you said that using the language name and extension is not a very elegant solution

Comment: @Rumesh If the script is called `connect_screen.py`, the command should be with language extension, else not. It is not that any of them causes a disaster,  but using no extension with scripts in `$PATH` (and no preceding `python3`) is the "good practice" way :), but not using `python3` would need the script to be executable.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I had already set it to be executable before so I guess I can just use `connect_screen`

Comment: @Rumesh perfect, but as said, then the script should be named likewise :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes I already renamed the script :) Thanks for all the help

Comment: Unfortunately, I did notice a slight increase in CPU load from xorg while using this script... Makes me hesitant about whether to use it or not.

Comment: Last night I noticed Netflix video streams were slightly skipping on regular intervals while using this script. I killed the script -- video is back to normal. This is a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved from following bash script as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xrandr=$(xrandr)

con_monitors=$(echo $xrandr | grep -c " connected ")

    if [[ $con_monitors -gt 1 ]]; then
        # All the layouts are saved in "screenlayout" folder.
        # eg cmd. xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output eDP-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 283x1440 --rotate normal --output DP-2 --off
        for layout in ~/.screenlayout/*.sh; do
            ./layout
        done
    fi
```

Comment: Bhaskar I know this answer was from ages ago but in case you're still around: 1. will this work automatically or does it need to be run manually / have a script run it every n seconds? 2. I have various screen layouts as bash scripts on my desktop, and didn't know about ./screenlayout - should I be using this preferentially? 3. could I modify this to change change xrandr AND audio settings when a scrren is turned on, AND change them back when that screen is turned off, do you think? Thanks!