# How to make an indicator to run various commands?

Tags: unity, bash, python, indicator, panel

How would I go about making an indicator for the panel on Unity?  I want a button that shows a menu and when you click on the menu items they run commands.

How do I do this?

Comment: This might interest you: http://askubuntu.com/a/853065/72216

Comment: Wait, I'll make an edited version of the answer for this one. Someone else will not easily find that answer as a match to this question, and I can make it more elegant, specific to this question.

Comment: Hi Christian, posted a slightly edited one, specifically to run *commands* rather than *scripts*. Another difference it that naming in this case may include spaces.

Comment: I wrote [indicator-script-runner](http://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335) for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### An indicator, running various commands

The answer below is an edited version of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/853065/72216). Since this *question* is quite different from that one, decided to specify the answer there to serve in a flexible way to this question, reading both (menu) names and commands from a text file.

[image]

#### The solution

Is an indicator, reading lines from a file, named `commands`, in which both the *name* and the *command* are defined, one set per line. Name (as it appears in the menu)  and command are separated by `||`. An example:

```
Gedit || gedit 
Go Home || nautilus $HOME
```

#### The script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3

currpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'update_setting'
        iconpath = currpath+"/icon.png"
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())

    def getscripts(self):
        cmd_data = [l for l in open(
            os.path.join(currpath, "commands")
            ).read().splitlines()]
        cmd_data = [l.split("||") for l in cmd_data]  
        for cmd in cmd_data:
            menuitem = Gtk.MenuItem(cmd[0].strip())
            menuitem.connect("activate", self.run_script, cmd[1].strip())
            self.menu.append(menuitem)

    def create_menu(self):
        self.menu = Gtk.Menu()
        self.getscripts()
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        sep = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        self.menu.append(sep)
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        self.menu.append(item_quit)
        self.menu.show_all()
        return self.menu

    def run_script(self, widget, script):
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", script])

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `run_commands.py`
2. Copy the icon below and save it as (exactly) `icon.png` in *one and the same folder* as the script.

   [image]
3. Create a text file, also *in one and the same folder*, (exactly) named: `commands` (no extension).
4. Populate the file with your commands and their names, like:

   ```
   Gedit || gedit 
   Go Home || nautilus $HOME
   ```

   Both the names may include spaces and the commands may include arguments.
5. Run the indicator by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/run_commands.py
   ```