# xrandr scale monitor output by default

Tags: display, xrandr, external-monitor

I've installed ubuntu on a retina Macbook Pro, and have managed to get the things to look at a reasonable size by scaling the display:

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --scale 0.9x0.9
```

When I connect my external monitor, I scale it like so:

```
xrandr --output DP-4 --scale 1.5x1.5
```

These work great, except after I unplug my external monitor and plug it back in again, I have to re-run the command to scale it to the size I would like.

How can I have this done automatically? (I would like to avoid just creating a macro to just run that command; I'd like it to run automatically each time I plug in my monitor)

Comment: Maybe look at https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug and see if that might be something you're looking for.

Comment: It seems like it should be such a primitive function of the OS; is there a way to do it without any third-party tools?

Comment: It's just showing scripts you can use and where to put them.  One that the GIT person already did.

Comment: I wrote an answer based on that.  Maybe it might work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run script when monitor is connected](http://askubuntu.com/questions/630202/run-script-when-monitor-is-connected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patterned from the scripts found [here](https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug) you can create your own.

First, create a `udev` script for the hot-plugging of your monitors.  Copy and paste the following in a terminal window:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "ACTION==\"change\", SUBSYSTEM==\"drm\", ENV{HOTPLUG}==\"1\", RUN+=\"/usr/local/bin/monitor-hotplug.sh\"" > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-monitor-hotplug.rules'
```

Then create your script that will be called from the udev:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "xrandr --output DP-4 --scale 1.5x1.5" > /usr/local/bin/monitor-hotplug.sh'
```

Then make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/monitor-hotplug.sh
```

You might have to reboot your host for this to take effect.

Hope this helps!