# xrandr fail. Bug or PEBKEC?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr, scaling

I have a dodgie old tv I want to use as a monitor, but its underscanning and no option to change in tv menu. I'm loosing the whole menu bar up top and most of the launcher

I have googled a lot and found two possible approaches to solve using xrandr

1 set underscan as per this page
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2141776&page=2&p=12643066#post12643066

2 Scale output
[xrandr scale monitor output by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874793/xrandr-scale-monitor-output-by-default/874798)

[Can I zoom out windows or scale the whole desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379123/can-i-zoom-out-windows-or-scale-the-whole-desktop)

Problem is when I try either of these options I get the same error message

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set underscan on
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  34
  Current serial number in output stream:  34

$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 0.9x0.9
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  26 (RRSetCrtcTransform)
  Value in failed request:  0x40
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

My xrandr output is

```
~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2646 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+1280+0 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0     60.0  
   960x720        60.0  
   928x696        60.1  
   896x672        60.0  
   960x600        60.0  
   960x540        60.0  
   800x600        60.0     60.3     56.2  
   840x525        60.0     59.9  
   800x512        60.2  
   700x525        60.0  
   640x512        60.0  
   720x450        59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
   680x384        59.8     60.0  
   576x432        60.1  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        60.3     56.3  
   320x240        60.1  
DP-1 disconnected
HDMI-1 connected 1280x720+0+48 708mm x 398mm
   1280x720       60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080      60.0     50.0     59.9     30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x576i       50.1  
   720x480        60.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x480i       60.1     60.1
```

Currently running 1280x720 because I get a bit less chopped off, but would prefer 1080 which is the monitors native res.

Any advice would be very welcome at this stage. I'm not great with CLI so very detailed instructions would be nice, then I might learn whats going on as well as copy pasting commands.

Comment: I'm also open to adding a custom resolution to workaround the tv if thats easier. Saw some threads on that but was a bit over my head.

Comment: I see someone else had this problem over a year ago https://askubuntu.com/questions/871558/xrandr-fail-to-set-custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1 and is still also waiting for an answer.

I would love to get this solved.