# command to change the value of a dconf entry which does not have a schema

Tags: gnome, bash, dconf, extension

I'm trying to change a setting of a gnome shell extension with a bash command.
The settings controls at what monitor and at which side of the screen the dock appears, which is part of the 'dash to dock' shell extension. I've tried:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock preferred-monitor 2
```

this gives the error message:

> No such schema 'org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock'

As indeed, none of the settings values of the shell extension entry in dconf have 'schemas'.

How can I change the values which do not have a schema in dconf, what command do I use? Ofcourse I can change them with the gui in dconf or with the settings menu of the extension, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! May I be so bold as to ask why you don't want a solution that you know works?

Comment: sure, I'm making a script that sets up my desktop after I connected my monitors. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/894109/possibility-to-save-the-current-resolution-wallpaper-and-desktop-arrangement-sehttp://askubuntu.com/questions/894109/possibility-to-save-the-current-resolution-wallpaper-and-desktop-arrangement-se
If I can add a command that changes this setting as well, the scipt does everything I need.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/894109/possibility-to-save-the-current-resolution-wallpaper-and-desktop-arrangement-se

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/863/change-primary-monitor

Comment: It's not really related to this question. I've already added the --primary flag to the xrandr command though, maybe you meant that. But lets keep the topic on changing this dconf value.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful...

Comment: I don't have the key, but `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock 2` should do. Can't test it though, so please try. Note that if a gsettings option exists, it is preferred. `gsettings` is higher level has a consistency check. It is the cli frontend to dconf.

Comment: It works! thanks. This was the command I used: dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/preferred-monitor 2

At first it didn't work for me but that's because I tried running it as root.

Comment: `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/preferred-monitor 2`