# Is it possible to automatically switch to HDMI sound output? 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound, hdmi

I've seen a few similar questions however couldn't find a solution and they were all a few years old.

When I plug my laptop into the TV HDMI port I have to manually go through the sound options and select HDMI to get the sound to play through the TV.  Is there a way to make it switch automatically on connection?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set HDMI sound output automatically on connect/disconnect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263248/set-hdmi-sound-output-automatically-on-connect-disconnect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not as easy as it looks at first sight to acchieve this. See the discussion below for reasons why it is in fact rather complicated:

- [Disucssion on implementing pulseaudio auto-switching of audio devices](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2012-March/013009.html)

The existing modules `module-switch-on-connect`, and `module-switch-on-port-available` will not work consistently with HDMI.

At present there is much effort being done to implement a priority list feature which will let us define the priority of an audio device for pulseaudio to route to it (or not):

- [Pulseaudio priority routing](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/RFC/PriorityRouting/)

Until this will be generally available in a future release of PulseAudio we have not much more choice than manually switching the audio output sink whenever we connect to a HDMI audio device.

To make life easier in case we often have to switch our output devices we may consider writing a small script to enable toggling between two output sinks. See these questions for a start:

- [How to change pulseaudio sink with  "pacmd set-default-sink" during playback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback)
- [How can I change the default audio device from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line/14083#14083)

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Automatically_switch_audio_to_HDMI

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an indicator applet that lets you switch the sound output.

As long as the problem is not solved, this applet is probably a bit more comfortable.

I'm using 12.04. Please let me know if you tried it successfully.

https://github.com/lkettenb/sound-output-switcher

Screentshot:

[image]

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 13.10 -- awesome! Thanks so much.

Comment: Not seem to be working properly on Ubuntu 14.04. BTW some people will need to install this first: `sudo apt-get install python-appindicator`

Comment: Doesn't work in Linux Mint 16

Comment: Works in Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1

Comment: `ImportError: No module named appindicator` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

For Gnome Shell users, the [Sound Output Device Chooser](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/) is a practical consolation, as long as there is no solution for auto-switching. This has been working well for me with Gnome Shell 3.14 and 3.16 so far.