# Ubuntu 15.10: Set HDMI sound automatically on connect/disconnect

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I've read on this SO question:
[Set HDMI sound output automatically on connect/disconnect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263248/set-hdmi-sound-output-automatically-on-connect-disconnect)

But it does not work.

Using `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo` does not work on terminal even though the profile exists.

How to do it for Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: Does the output work at all?

Comment: Those scripts have been updated for more modern versions.  They should work just fine for you/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set HDMI sound output automatically on connect/disconnect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263248/set-hdmi-sound-output-automatically-on-connect-disconnect)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between internal and HDMI speakers automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854055/switch-between-internal-and-hdmi-speakers-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

I had to use `pacmd set-default-sink` rather than `pactl set-card-profile`. To be able to use it in a script, you must export `PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH` also. Create `/usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle`:

```
#!/bin/sh
HDMI_STATUS=`cat /sys/class/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1/status`
export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH="/run/user/1000/pulse/"

if [ $HDMI_STATUS = "connected" ]
then
    sudo -u zed -E pacmd set-default-sink 0
else
    sudo -u zed -E pacmd set-default-sink 1
fi
```

Where `zed` is my username and `1000` is my UID.
`chmod` the file to 0755.

Create a udev rule at `/etc/udev/rules.d/hdmi_sound.rule` as sudo:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle"
```

Restart udev rules:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

You can test that the udev rules works using `udevadm monitor --property`.