# Set HDMI sound output automatically on connect/disconnect to specific device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I want a way to swap from internal speakers to HDMI for sound output, but only when I connect to a certain device. I want this to happen when I connect to my TV, but not my external monitor (which doesn't have speakers).

I used the Daniel answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263248/set-hdmi-sound-output-automatically-on-connect-disconnect) to add a script that swaps the sound to HDMI automatically when I plug in the cable. (I wanted to ask this in the question, but I don't have the rep to comment)>

Can I add a rule to this script so that it swaps based on device name?