# How do I get an ssh -X session to use the host's sound settings

Tags: sound, ssh, pulseaudio

I have a USB sound card on a host system which has all my music, and to which I have connected my living room speakers.

I would like to use my laptop to ssh -X into that system and run my favorite music player remotely, so that sound is played on the USB sound card on the host system.

However, when I ssh in, and start the music player, it does not seem to see my sound settings there (even though I'm logged in with the same user with which I would normally log in) and will only play using the internal sound card.

Is there a way that I can make the ssh session pick up the (I assume) pulseaudio settings that I get on normal logins?

Comment: Have you tried using NX instead of `ssh -X` ? It still goes through SSH, will make the session faster, and supports audio export: http://www.nomachine.com/ar/view.php?ar_id=AR03D00355

Comment: It is not X but for just sound output selection from ssh you may be successful with [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/72076/3940)

Comment: I have tried NX (and VNC), but what I really like about X forwarding is that it lets me just run a single application remotely, so there are no scaling issues, and in general it seems much more responsive that at least VNC. (I didn't get far with NX, I must admit.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pulse-client.conf` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/pulse-client.conf.5.html) suggests you may be able to set the PULSE_SERVER environment variable to change which pulseaudio it talks to. So if you

1. on the host machine run `xprop -root PULSE_SERVER >
   pulseaudio-server.txt`
2. ssh -X (or actually ssh -Y is better) to that machine with the
   laptop
3. run `export PULSE_SERVER=` to whatever `xprop -root PULSE_SERVER`
   said
4. run your music player

Answer via [+Ray Strode](https://plus.google.com/116015965439782966698/posts/CFWcjKgV6tF) on google+

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 I just get: `PULSE_SERVER:  no such atom on any window.`