# How do I run a script on a dbus signal?

Tags: automation, dbus

Is it possible to run a script on an arbitrary dbus signal? Something like Upstart that runs as an unprivileged user and doesn't require root perms to modify?

I ask because I've already written a silly script that [waits for bluetooth events to start my music player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138522/how-do-i-run-a-script-when-a-bluetooth-device-connects). Now I'd like to do something similar when my machine connects to specific networks, or other devices attach.

**EDIT:** My original question didn't specify this, but I meant "associate a number of scripts with one of a set of events" - so I'd have the same launcher-y thing (like Upstart) that manages a number of scripts, each of which cares about a different dbus signal. All in user space.

Comment: Maybe it isn't exactly what you look for, but poped-up in my mind when you talked about upstart. [You can trigger scripts with systemd](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted/679600#679600). I'm not exactly sure what type of unit creates your bluetooth device, but I think there is one.

Answer (score 21):

You need the [`dbus-monitor`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dbus-monitor.1.html)

The script will look something like

```bash
#!/bin/bash

interface=org.gnome.Rhythmbox.Player
member=playingUriChanged

# listen for playingUriChanged DBus events,
# each time we enter the loop, we just got an event
# so handle the event, e.g. by printing the artist and title
# see rhythmbox-client --print-playing-format for more output options

dbus-monitor --profile "interface='$interface',member='$member'" |
while read -r line; do
  printf "Now playing: "
  rhythmbox-client --print-playing
done
```

Taken from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5345462/854477).

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a simple tool for this purpose: https://github.com/jluttine/dbus-listen

The same example as in the other answer could look as follows. Write the script that should be executed when the signal is received:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
printf "Now playing: "
rhythmbox-client --print-playing
```

Listen to the signal (assuming the above script is named `myscript.sh`):

```bsh
dbus-listen --interface org.gnome.Rhythmbox.Player --member playingUriChanged myscript.sh
```

The other answer using `dbus-monitor` doesn't work when you need to listen to the system bus.