# How to trigger a script when an external USB disk is mounted?

Tags: usb, mount, scripts, external-hdd

I need to automatically copy images off a camera when it is inserted into the USB port.
I've written a script to do the copying, and I've found that, by creating a file

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/95-my-own.rules
```

with the line

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sdg1", RUN+="/path/to/my/script"
```

I can invoke the script when a USB device (such as the camera) is inserted.

The script is invoked at a time when the disk hasn't been mounted yet.
My workaround is to make the script start the copying process in the background after some `sleep` to give it time for the file system to be mounted, but it would be better to trigger the script right after the file system has been mounted.

How?

Answer (score 1):

The following may work:

Run dbus-monitor before you mount the USB and see what events it generates when the USB is mounted.

Then do something like this [How do I run a script on a dbus signal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150790/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-a-dbus-signal)

Comment: I'll let you know when I have time to try this out ...

Comment: This is more what he was looking for... http://www.danplanet.com/blog/2007/11/11/using-dbus-to-take-action-on-a-usb-storage-device/