# How can I get sound on headphones without switching back to 'Speakers' manually?

Tags: 12.04, alsa, headphones, realtek

On my Notebook (with Realtek ALC269VB) the sound over speakers works well until I plugin the headphones, Speakes get muted as expected but no sound on headphones. I noticed that as soon as I plugin the headphones, Alsamixer, Ubuntu Sound Control and pavucontrol switched to 'Headphones' which have no effect (does not really exist). When I switch back to 'Speakers' everything is fine; I can control the sound of headphones. This is a kind of work-around (starting pavucontrol to switch from Headphones to Speakers) but not relly satisfying.

My complete sound [configuration](http://www.rum3ber.ch/tmp/sound_config.txt) and a screenshot of [Alsamixer](http://www.rum3ber.ch/tmp/alsamixer.png).

You may notice that Alsamixer says 'Intel Cougarpoint HDMI' instead of 'Intel HDA Realtec ALC269VB' what it did two days ago. Anyway, I couldn't find any differences between it.

My question:

In order to easy the work-around: is there a command line option to switch to 'Speakers'?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback

Comment: In the first place I'm looking for a solution that avoids the problem at all: How to avoid that an input (sound) is switched from sink 'Speakers' to a not existing sink 'Headphones' when I plugin my headphones? Thanks to Takkat for the work-around link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulseaudio always tries to switch to a newly available audio port when it becomes available. To stop this we can edit our `default.pa`. This file is located in `/etc/pulse` (defining settings for all users) or in `~/.pulse` (to override these settings for a single user). Just comment out this line to stop pulseaudio from switching ports as follows:

```
# load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

To take effect we need to restart pulseaudio server with `pulseaudio -k` (or restarting our session).

> Whenever you edit the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` please make a backup first to be able to restore previous settings in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, now it works perfectly. By the way, restarting the session is not enough but 'pulseaudio -k' makes it happen.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Now I have the same volume state for the speakers and headphones. Is it possible to save and restore the volume states when pluging/unpluging the headphones ?