# Unable to get sound in headset on Ubuntu 13.4

Tags: sound, dv6

i've download and installed ubuntu 13.4

mostly every thing work but i have a problem in the sound !

when i run some song the sound work perfectly but when i connect my head set i have no sound

running UBUNTU 13.4 on HP-pavilion **dv6-6c65se**

best regards.,

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what headset you're using.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I get sound on headphones without switching back to 'Speakers' manually?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140454/how-can-i-get-sound-on-headphones-without-switching-back-to-speakers-manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

l have HP dv6 and was having the same problem. l fixed it by terminal / alsamixer.

Open a terminal. (The quickest way is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut.)
Enter `alsamixer”` and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
You will now see a user interface. In this user interface, you can do the following:

1. Select your correct sound card using <kbd>F6</kbd> and select <kbd>F5</kbd> to see recording controls as well
2. Move around with <kbd>left arrow</kbd> and <kbd>right arrow</kbd> keys.
3. Increase and decrease volume with <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys.
4. Mute / Unmute with the <kbd>M</kbd> key. An <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> means muted, and <kbd>O</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> means unmuted.
5. Exit from alsamixer with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

A caveat here: When you mute or unmute something, pulseaudio might pick it up and mute and unmute other controls, as well as PulseAudio’s main mute.