# A2DP connection not shown in PulseAudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I'm trying to pipe the audio ouput to my Belkin Z73 bluetooth receiver but once connected and paired with the key `0000` the receiver doesn't show up in PulseAudio. Furthermore the following command

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo sink=bluez_source.00:02:72:EA:95:61
```

returns `Failure: Module initalization failed`.

Does someone know what's going on?
Is there anything else I could try to pipe the audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=bluetooth
```

should add `alsa_output.bluetooth` to

```
pactl list sinks short
```

Then switch to this sink by following the directions described in the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback/72076#72076) given by Takkat

Comment: On Debian testing the first command fails with the message "Module initialization failed."

Answer (score 3):

The [module-loopback](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules#module-loopback) is used to

> route audio from a source directly back to a sink.

The way you issued it you are trying to loop an output sink to an input device. This obviously won't work, thus the "initialization failed" error.

In case you want to have your audio on both sinks, the local sound card, and the bluetooth receiver use **module-combine-sink**.

To connect to a bluetooth sink you need to have this sink recognized by pulseaudio. Check with the following command if this sink is present before you try to connect to it:

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

If you can see your Bluetooth receiver you can connect it outlined in my answer to this question:

- [How to change pulseaudio sink with  "pacmd set-default-sink" during playback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback/72076#72076)

In case your receiver is not listed there may be an issue connecting it to Bluetooth  (Bluez/Blueman depending on your distribution). You may then try if removing the device from the list of known devices and redoing the pairing process helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem with my N04 Belkin. [brillout's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/145883/22949) helped me as well. But then i noticed that `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` wasn't installed. So i installed it, and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Xubuntu 12.10, installing [pulseaudio-module-bluetooth [image: Install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pulseaudio-module-bluetooth) made it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in Ubuntu 13.10 and pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=bluetooth didn't help.  The device haven't appeared in the list.

What had helped is adding the device in the ~/.asoundrc and loading it manually:

```
pulseaudio -k
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start

echo pcm.btheadset {\
        type bluetooth\
        device 20:13:03:23:08:55\
        profile "a2dp"\
} > ~/.asoundrc



aplay -D btheadset -f s16_le /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav

pulseaudio -D
pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-device  
pactl unload-module module-alsa-card
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=btheadset sink_name=btheadset sink_properties=device.description=Headphones
```

Make sure that:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez-tools bluez-utils bluez-alsa bluez-audio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo apt-get remove blueman
```