# Pulse Audio Bluetooth card profile not displaying on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, a2dp

I am running `Ubuntu 12.10` and don't see a bluez_card profile on my system:

```
$ pactl list cards short
0   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0  module-alsa-card.c
```

I tried to load the module as suggested here [12.04 - Bluetooth headset disappeared](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12336309)

```
$ pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=bluetooth
Failure: Timeout
```

I am trying to get the Bluetooth card profile to display so that I can set it up like it is done here : [Why did my Bluetooth headset disappear from Sound Settings and how can I get it back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175933/why-did-my-bluetooth-headset-disappear-from-sound-settings-and-how-can-i-get-it)

```
$ pactl list cards short
0   alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1  module-alsa-card.c
1   alsa_card.usb-Generic_Turtle_Beach_USB_Headset_0000000001-00-Headset    module-alsa-card.c
2   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2  module-alsa-card.c
8   bluez_card.C8_84_47_04_21_6F    module-bluetooth-device.c

$ pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.C8_84_47_04_21_6F a2dp
```

## Update

I have the `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` package installed. I tried loading the module `module-bluetooth-discover` but nothing happens. How can I set this up in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`?

Now in the sound settings the `Ouput` tab is selected but under where it says `Play sound through` there are no items showing anymore.

When i try listing all of the profile cards it says `Connection failure`

```
$ pactl list cards short
Connection failure: Connection refused
```

## Update #2

The answer to this post :
[Sound settings panel empty on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170955/sound-settings-panel-empty-on-12-04) 
helped me solve the no sound options problem.

However, I am now back to:

```
$ pactl list cards short
0   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0  module-alsa-card.c
```

## Update #3

After uninstalling and reinstalling the `pulseaudio` package, I tried loading the bluetooth module `module-bluetooth-discover`. The first time I ran it, it output `Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.` 
Then I checked the profile cards but no bluetooth card displays:

```
$ pactl list cards short 
0 alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0    module-alsa-card.c
```

I loaded the bluetooth module again and this time it output: 
`Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information. >>> Module load failed.`

I checked and now the bluetooth card displays. Strange behavior, but it works now. Thanks @Takkat.

## Update #4

This just went out again. I tried removing and reinstalling the `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` package, and loading the module `module-bluetooth-discover` but i am back to where I started.

```
$ pactl list cards short 
0 alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 module-alsa-card.c
```

## Update #5

After installing recent updates from the Update Manager and restarting my machine it is back to working:

```
$ pactl list cards short
0   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0  module-alsa-card.c 
1   bluez_card.00_0C_8A_53_70_D0    module-bluetooth-device.c
```

This whole Bluetooth setup in `12.10` is very unpredictable.  Hopefully this gets shored up in `13.04`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable bluetooth from pulseaudio we need to make sure we have the follwing package installed:

- [pulseaudio-module-bluetooth](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pulseaudio-module-bluetooth) [image: Install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth]

Then we also need to load the **module-bluetooth-discover** to make use of a Bluetooth audio device from pulseaudio.

```
pacmd load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

This can also be done from our `default.pa` to be loaded on starting the pulseaudio sound server.

Comment: This was very useful. Anyway it is not possible to choose *Stereo* mode in my "Jabra Halo" headset, but only low quality. In Raring 13.04 it worked...

Comment: @leonardvertighel See if your device has a2dp profile `pacmd list-cards`. See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159064/switch-between-speaker-bluetooth-stereo-bluetooth-mono/159245#159245 for more on changing profile from CLI.

Comment: Works for me, Ubuntu 16!