# How to create/simulate two audio lines/devices?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I have searched around the internet for answers; however, I was not successful in locating an answer. What is the best method of simulating two audio devices using Pulse Audio/ALSA/something else? Thank you.

Edit: For further clarification, I need these audio devices for input and output into Teamspeak 3. This setup will allow me to create a music bot of sorts when I play audio into the line that is the input of teamspeak. This setup is easily achieved through Virtual Audio Cable on Windows. Thank you.

Comment: To better advice you it may be worth you said a word on the purpose why you need those simulated device.

Comment: Sorry to not have gotten back to you earlier, I did not notice your edit. May it be that s a loopback sink meets your needs? See http://askubuntu.com/a/168338/3940

Comment: Have you tried asking in the #pulseaudio in IRC chat or the mailing list ? here is their wiki http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Community

Answer (score 0):

Using alsa, you can add in `~/.asoundrc`

```
pcm.simulatedAudio {
  type file
  slave {
    pcm null
  }
  format "raw"
   file " | /path/to/script"
}
```

This will run the script sending the audio data in to stdin (if you dont want the audio you can pipe it in to /dev/null).