# No sound via headphones with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound, headphones

HI have looked through some similar questions, but none of the answers I've tried have helped me. Alsamixer channel is not muted and when I switch to headphone output via pulseaudio there is still no sound. Internal speakers are muted.

I found another surprising behavior that might be related to my problem. When I have no headphones plugged in and use alsamixer to mute the headphones channel, then Master, Headphones and Speaker channels all become muted.

```
user@user:~$ pulseaudio --dump-conf
### Read from configuration file: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-3.0/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = auto
log-level = notice
resample-method = speex-float-1
enable-remixing = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 6
default-channel-map = front-left,front-left-of-center,front-center,front-right,front-right-of-center,rear-center
default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 1000000
```

Please let me know if you need any other information that I can provide - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem. After many hours spending on configuring, reinstalling and installing different versions of alsa (using many guides from www) I broke my system... :/

After reinstalling ubuntu I founded "stupid" solution. I went to `alsamixer` (terminal function) and change Auto-Mute-Mode. It disabled digital output. Problems have gone.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same problem, wich was fixed in my case by removing pavucontrol, rebooting, and installing pavucontrol again, and changing some configurations in the config tab.

Hope this can be useful for the future.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, Ubuntu 13.10 seems not to switch the audio automatically to headphones now.
You have to go to Sound Configuration and select the Headphones instead of HDMI.
For an automatic solution check this: https://askubuntu.com/a/72076/206170

Comment: Thanks, but I checked that and that was not the issue.