# How to change an audio output device by a keyboard hotkey (or a command shortcut)?

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'd like to have a faster way of changing `audio out device` (between `internal notebook's` [or a headphones] and HDMI `external monitor's`) instead of opening `sound settings`, which has to load and requires too much clicking for an action so simple and repeatable.

Preferably a change from the device being used to a next (not used) sound device, but static change (to A or to B) would be nice as well!

I can imagine keyboard hotkey binding or making a command shortcut, eventually installing additional software.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback for a way to switch a running audio stream to another sink.