# How do I switch the audio outputs of an audio device from CLI?

Tags: command-line, xorg, pulseaudio, desktop-environments

I'm trying to switch between the audio outputs of my video card from the command line. I'm able to do that via the GUI settings, as it's shown on the picture. **How can I do this programmatically?**

[image]

On the picture are presented two audio devices wit two outputs each:

- (green) Device 1 - **Built-in Audio** with two outputs:

  - Digital Output
  - Headphones
- (red)        Device 2 - **HDMI Audio Controller** of NVidia GTX 660. To the video card are connected two monitors:

  - The first monitor is **LG TV** and it is connected to **HDMI-0**.
  - The second monitor is **LG ULTRAWIDE** and it is connected to **DVI-I-1**.

So I want to switch, via the command-line, between the *red* outputs (the two monitors). Everything I've found, in my research, is how to switch between the audio devices (sound cards). I've already read few topics as these questions:

- [Audio output device, fast switch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4055/audio-output-device-fast-switch)
- [How to change pulseaudio sink with  "pacmd set-default-sink" during playback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback)
- [How can I choose the audio output device using the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470839/how-can-i-choose-the-audio-output-device-using-the-terminal)
- [How to switch sound output with key shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156895/how-to-switch-sound-output-with-key-shortcut)

---

When the first monitor **LG TV** | **HDMI-0** is engaged as audio output:

[image]

```bsh
$ pactl list sinks short
8   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
16  alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING

$ pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
```

- [output of `pactl list sinks`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CY89DkxYQM/)
- [output of `pacmd list-sinks`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cQyk2WryMb/)

---

When the second monitor **LG ULTRAWIDE** | **DVI-I-1** is engaged as audio output:

[image]

```bsh
$ pactl list sinks short
8   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
17  alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING

$ pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
```

- [output of `pactl list sinks`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2NC4T3hzDc/)
- [output of `pacmd list-sinks`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SNgsSndynQ/)

---

The output of `pacmd list-cards` and `pactl list cards` is provided [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y2Bd7K6hrB/).

---

You can see (in this particular case) I'm searching for a way to switch between `sink 16` and `sink 17`. But when `sink 16` is presented in `pactl list sinks`, `sink 17` is not presented and vice versa. I can switch them only from the GUI settings. Is ithere a way to do that via the command-line?

Comment: `pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo` or `pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1`?

Comment: @Thomas, if I understood your suggestion correctly  the result is [`Failure: No such entity`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bSsrbTHjPJ/).

Comment: There is not sink `alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo` but `alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1`. Don't get the point from your link?

Comment: @Thomas, I've updated the question.

Comment: Ah, got it...sorry. I think you have to change the profile as well. Can you test with `pactl set-card-profile 1 hdmi-stereo` and see if the sink list changes. After that you should be able to change to the `...stereo` sink. If not, please also add the output of `pactl list cards short`.

Comment: Hi, @Thomas, thanks to your help I've solved the task. We can find all available **profiles** for each **card name** by: [`pacmd list-cards`/`pactl list cards`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y2Bd7K6hrB/). The correct syntax of the commands is: (1) `pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1 output:hdmi-stereo` and (2) `pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1 output:hdmi-stereo-extra1`. (Where `alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1` is the **card name** and `output:hdmi-stereo*` are the **profile names**.) These commands creates new `sinc #` and deletes the previews `sinc #` of this card.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74032/discussion-between-pa4080-and-thomas).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to the discussion with [@Thomas](https://askubuntu.com/users/490838/thomas) I realised the proper therms (key words) are *profile* and *card*. In the terms of the question *profiles* are the *inputs* and *outputs*. The *cards* are the *audio devices*. And the *sink* numbers are not so important, but we need them.

We can find all available profiles for each card name by the command `pacmd list-cards` or `pactl list cards` that outputs the same information:

```bsh
$ pactl list cards

Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0
    ...
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 60, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6060, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: yes)
        ...
    Active Profile: output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    ...

Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1
    ...
    Profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5400, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: yes)
        ...
    Active Profile: output:hdmi-stereo
    ...
```

A certain profile can be set by command with format as this:

```bsh
pactl set-card-profile output:hdmi-stereo <card name|number> <profile name>
```

According to the question for the four mentioned outputs the commands are:

```bsh
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1 output:hdmi-stereo # LG ULTRAWIDE
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1 output:hdmi-stereo-extra1 # LG TV
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 output:iec958-stereo # Digital Output
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 output:analog-stereo # Headphones
```

As it is shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/18210/566421), when the new profile is set next things to do are:

```bsh
 pacmd set-default-sink <sink number of the target profile>
 pacmd move-sink-input "$i" <sink number of the target profile> 
 # where $i is the index number of any active input: pacmd list-sink-inputs
```

---

According to my needs, described in the question, I've created the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Name: /usr/local/bin/audioswitch
# Usage: audioswitch; audioswitch 1; audioswitch 2;  audioswitch 3; audioswitch 4

CARD_1="pci-0000_03_00.1"             ### HDMI Audio Controller of NVidia GTX 660
CARD_1_PROFILE_1="hdmi-stereo"          # LG ULTRAWIDE
CARD_1_PROFILE_2="hdmi-stereo-extra1"   # LG TV
CARD_0="pci-0000_00_1b.0"             ### Built-in Audio
CARD_0_PROFILE_1="iec958-stereo"        # Digital Output
CARD_0_PROFILE_2="analog-stereo"        # Headphones

# Read the user's input
CHOICE="${@}"
choice() {
    if   [ "$CHOICE" == 1 ]; then CARD="$CARD_1"; PROF="$CARD_1_PROFILE_1" # LG ULTRAWIDE
    elif [ "$CHOICE" == 2 ]; then CARD="$CARD_1"; PROF="$CARD_1_PROFILE_2" # LG TV
    elif [ "$CHOICE" == 3 ]; then CARD="$CARD_0"; PROF="$CARD_0_PROFILE_1" # Digital Output
    elif [ "$CHOICE" == 4 ]; then CARD="$CARD_0"; PROF="$CARD_0_PROFILE_2" # Headphones
    else
        echo -e "\nYou should choice between:"
        echo -e "\n\t[1] LG ULTRAWIDE\n\t[2] LG TV\n\t[3] Digital Output\n\t[4] Headphones\n"
        echo -n "Your choice: "; read CHOICE; echo; choice; # call the function again
    fi
}; choice # call the function

# Set the choosen card profile as sink
pactl set-card-profile "alsa_card.${CARD}" "output:${PROF}";

# Set the default sink to the new one
pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_output.${CARD}.${PROF}" &> /dev/null

# Redirect the existing inputs to the new sink
for i in $(pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep index | awk '{print $2}'); do
    pacmd move-sink-input "$i" "alsa_output.${CARD}.${PROF}" &> /dev/null
done
```

The script is ready to be used with [custom keyboard shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/a/591605/566421), because it can handle the value (`1`-`4`) of the first positional parameter. When it is called without additional paraneter it will ask for your choice:

```
$ audioswitch 

You should choice between:

    [1] LG ULTRAWIDE
    [2] LG TV
    [3] Digital Output
    [4] Headphones

Your choice: 1
```

Comment: Notes for further improvements:  [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1017582/566421); [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/226284/566421); [3](https://askubuntu.com/a/18210/566421).

Comment: very useful script.. I am not getting your point of "The script is ready to be used with custom keyboard shortcuts, because it can handle the value (1-4) of the first positional parameter. When it is called without additional parameter it will ask for your choice:"

Comment: So one needs to set all the 4 commands as keyboard shortcuts rite? Not the one keyboard shortcut that can ask for choice..

Comment: Hi, @PRATAP, yes, you are right. I'm using this script together with another script (based on xrandr) that switches the video output. So my shortcut commands look like: `audioswitch 1 && videoswitch 1`, `audioswitch 2 && videoswitch 2`, etc. If you need interactive application - there is a nice gnome extension that allows to switch the audio outputs directly from a toolbar menu.