# Use pavucontrol via Command Line

Tags: 16.04, server, sound, pulseaudio, pavucontrol

I am trying to set the input and output sinks for 2 applications on `pavucontrol` (PulseAudio Volume Control). I can do it on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop:

[image: Vol Control]

But on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS I cannot seem to do it (via `pacmd` or `pactl`).

How can this be done?

Comment: "I cannot seem to do it"? Did you try it?

Comment: Of course, I tried via pacmd or pactl..

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: I could not find the the recording application (sources), it was not listed. Also, I could not find a command that will specify a specific input or output sink to that application

Comment: I found a good answer for this here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208784/246486

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I switch the audio outputs of an audio device from CLI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011806/how-do-i-switch-the-audio-outputs-of-an-audio-device-from-cli)