# HDMI audio disabled after resuming from sleep

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, spdif

Whenever I resume my Ubuntu 17.04 from sleep the HDMI audio output is disabled, and audio has defaulted to the SP-DIF output. I always have to run pavucontrol or go into sound settings to re-select HDMI as the audio output.
As this is a Home Theatre PC running Kodi this is a pain in the neck, as it can't be done using the IR remote.
Is there any way that I can resolve this, either by disabling the SP-DIF output altogether or automatically selecting the HDMI audio device whenever resuming from sleep?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [complicated way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#HDMI_output_configuration) of accomplishing this with `udev` rules, `systemd` service and suspend/resume hooks.

An easier way is to check this:

```
$ cat /etc/pulse/default.pa | grep switch-on-port-available
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

If the second line doesn't begin with a `#` (commented out) then edit the file and insert a `#` in the beginning.

Now all output will be controlled to what you manually set it to and stay there until you change it.

Comment: It was already commented out in my case, but running this command brings back the option ... "pulseaudio --kill" ....  I hope it helps, Always trying to help, Mark

Answer (score -1):

For the benefit of anyone who hits this problem....Following advice given on another forum I upgraded my kernel from 4.10 to 4.15 and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Ignore that - the problem has returned today :0(

Comment: FWIW here's the link where I got the advice anyway...https://forums.digitalspy.com/discussion/comment/89613656#Comment_89613656

Comment: I tried editing default.pa, commenting out the "load-module module-switch-on-port-available" line. Now the HDMI audio is playing everything back weirdly slowly - at about a quarter of normal speed ???