# PulseAudio: Setting a default sink for created sink inputs

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

From what I can tell, each time youtube loads a new video, it changes the index of the sink input that it uses, or creates a new sink input to use for that new video and trashes the old one. The default sink I want to use is Sink 3, but it always uses sink 2, despite the default sink being set to 3 (there's an asterisk next to sink 3 in "pacmd list-sinks"). I constantly have to call "pacmd move-sink-input [index] 3" each time I load a new video. Do y'all know a way to get the default sink to use sink 3 always? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

:) 1st, high votes *Related Question* should point you to solution:

[image: related question hint]

---

[How to change pulseaudio sink with “pacmd set-default-sink” during playback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback)

- You may need to **disable stream target device restore** by editing the corresponding line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to:

  ```
  load-module module-stream-restore restore_device=false
  ```
- Then try:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
  ```

  Reference: [ArchLinux Forums: Flash ignores pulseaudio](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=103819)

Comment: That's the thread I used, actually to get to the point where I'm at. I've done the restore_device=false thing already as well.

Comment: @user301723, I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately those things were already installed. I did find an alternative way around it, which I posted as an answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I decided just to take the hacky way out. I created a bash script:

File: move-sink-input

```
#!/bin/bash
index=`pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep index: | grep -v "index: 0"`
index=${index:11}
if [ $index ]; then
    pacmd move-sink-input $index 3
fi
```

Then I created another bash script:

File: move-sink-input-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    move-sink-input
    sleep 1
done
```

I then kick this off with "move-sink-input-loop > /dev/null &".

tl;dr: I wrote a script that moved the latest input every second.

The reason why I needed a second script for the loop is that somehow the result of "pacmd list-sink-inputs" stays the same within a running instance of a script, so doing the loop in another script to kick off the initial script seemed to actually update the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use KDE I think I've found the solution.

In start-pulseaudio-x11 script that is used to autostart pulse, there is this clause:

```
if [ x"$KDE_FULL_SESSION" = x"true" ]; then
    /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-device-manager "do_routing=1" > /dev/null
fi
```

My guess is that it gives KDE a way to control the sinks and makes pulseaudio ignore the default sink that you've set with pacmd... Well, there is no KDE tool that controls the sinks anyway so you better just remove this clause altogether - and then the default sink setting works, for me.