# Trying to change PulseAudio application sink/source from command line

Tags: command-line, sound, pulseaudio

I have two applications on startup, which I link together with loopbacks and null sinks. Everything works great, except everytime I start them I have to open pavucontrol and manually change the sink/source for each application. I know there is a command to change the default sink, but that doesn't help. I want to be able to assign a sink or source to each application's input and output without opening pavucontrol. There is obviously a way to do this (as pavucontrol is doing behind the scenes) I just can't find any documentation or anyone else who has done this before.

Images to demonstrate:

[image: PulseAudio]
**This is the setting I want to change.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than canging the default sink we can move a sink input or a source output to another sink or source using [`pactl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pactl.1.html) (or `pacmd`).

> `move-sink-input ID SINK`
>   Move the specified playback stream (identified by its  numerical index) to the specified sink (identified by its symbolic name or numerical index).
>
> `move-source-output ID SOURCE`
>   Move the specified recording stream (identified by its numericalindex)  to the specified source (identified by its symbolic name or numerical index).

To list existing streams we can issue

```
pactl list sink-inputs
pactl list source-outputs
```

These can then be moved by index to another location given by index (or name), e.g.

```
pactl move-sink-input 5 1
```

Also see [How to change pulseaudio sink with  "pacmd set-default-sink" during playback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback) for using pacmd.

Comment: I did discover these commands when reading man pactl. The problem is, will these applications have the same index value every time they are started? I highly doubt it. I don't understand why other arguments to pactl can take the name of the stream as an argument, but these two cannot. I was thinking perhaps use grep or awk to deterime the index based on pactl list... but I am not well versed in either of those tools.

Comment: No, the index will change with each stream on a given sink/source.