# Switch pulseaudio sound output, when bluetooth headset is connected, for running applications

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

There are a bunch of hints how to automatically switch the output of pulseaudio to a bluetooth headset when it's connected.

But they still don't help with switching the output of running applications without having to restart them.

For example, I have a running VirtualBox machine, decide to use my bluetooth headset, while it's already running.

Right now I don't know any other way of hearing the virtual machine on my bluetooth headset, than to restart the machine.

**Can I switch the output while it's still running?**

I don't need advice on automatically switching pulseaudio's output device to the bluetooth headset as soon as it's connected. But a way to switch the output of already running applications.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with [moving the stream](https://askubuntu.com/a/72076/3940) from internal to bluetooth and back?

Comment: Yes I did. Before and right now again to be sure. The output device of the running application remains the device that was active in pulseaudio's settings GUI when the application was started. Nothing seems to change that, apart from restarting the application.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: There must be a way... I can't dig deeper into that atm - maybe later on today.

Comment: With my Bluetooth on (16.04.3 HWE) I still have issues with A2DP but other than that I can't reproduce the behaviour you have. Switching between Bluetooth and internal audio works fine. Did you disable [stream target device restore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback)? Is your VirtualBox audio driver set to PulseAudio?