# How do you set headphones as default in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: sound, headphones

I'm using a Dell Precision 3560 and running Ubuntu 20.04. I have 2 monitors set up using a Dell D6000 Docking station.

Anytime I unplug or replug in the Docking Station, it changes the input and output sound devices and doesn't keep headphones as the input and output.

Is there anyway I can set it, so that it doesn't switch what device is connected when plugged or unplugged?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, D6000 Docking station has an HDMI port, an audio port 3.5 mm line-out (rear) and a headphone & microphone combo port (front). Which one do you want to use include a headphones jack on your laptop? Have you read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367276/audio-always-routed-to-docking-station-no-sound?rq=1) answer?

Comment: i don't want to use any of them. That question isn't the same as mine at all. My issue is the computer thinks the docking station is a speaker in addition to a docking station when it isn't. So whenever I plug the docking station it, it sets it as default instead of my headset that is plugged directly into the computer.

Comment: edit your question and paste output of `pactl list sinks`