# How to bind custom commands to keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I have arrived at 11.10, installed gnome-shell and wondered where I can bind my custom commands to keyboard shortcuts.

In Compiz I used the simple and efficient "commands" plugin. How to do that in gnome-shell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set up your shortcuts in the Keyboard section of System Settings. You can either open System Settings in the Activities search or use the upper-right menu.

[image: Main menu screenshot]

Then open Keyboard.

[image: Keyboard in System Settings]

You'll see a section for Custom Shortcuts on the bottom left-hand side, if what you're changing is not already present in a section above.

[image: Shortcuts in Keyboard settings]

These instructions may also be of use in Unity.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by commandline?