# How can I manage keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

In 10.04, I've had a keyboard shortcut defined via it's keyboard settings applet.

Recently I have upgraded to 11.10 (I use gnome-classic). This shortcut still works, but I can't find it in System Setting's Keyboard applet. This means I don't know how to disable it.

Not that it bothers me too much (now, at least), but not being able to control my own computer doesn't seem very pleasant.

Where does Ubuntu store my keyboard shortcuts?

BTW, I do not use compiz, and I can't find my shortcut in gconf either.

**update**

Sory, I have just remembered, that shortcut was defined using xbindkey, so it has nothing to do with gnome/unity/whatever. Thanks for your attempts to help me and sorry for your wasted time. The question should probably be deleted.

Comment: gconf is being deprecated. Check dconf (you can do so with `gsettings` or `dconf-editor`)

Comment: You can find keyboard shortcut settings in `gnome-control-center`. Click on the keyboard icon, then the shortcuts tab.

Comment: Related question (or possible duplicate): http://askubuntu.com/q/73473/18612

Comment: I could not find it in dconf too. And gnome-control-center is what I've called System Settings in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The second post above is correct. If you hit the <kbd>SuperKey</kbd> and in the search bar of the Unity Dash type in: `gnome-control-center` or just the word: `keyboard`, an Icon labeled Keyboard will appear. Click on that, and switch to the second tab, in order to add and view existing shortcuts.

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts Tab]

Comment: As I have said, I can't find my shortcut in the System Setting's Keyboard applet. That's exactly the window you talk about.