# Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to cause the Looking Glass to appear?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, shortcut-keys, javascript

On Ubuntu 11.10, using GNOME Shell, I find myself using the "Looking Glass" JavaScript Console very much. I know how to assign desktop shortcuts in general; but, this seems a little unusual.

Instead of typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>`lg`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, I'd like to assign a shortcut key to perform this. However, shortcuts normally require a command file and there's the rub. I am unaware of a command file for the looking glass tool.

How can I set a keyboard shortcut to perform the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>`lg`<kbd>Enter</kbd> keystrokes?

**Clarification**:  Instead of pressing a 4-key sequence, I want to use a 1-key shortcut to invoke `lg`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this GNOME extension to assign a keyboard shortcut to activate looking-glass.

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/313/helpful-keybindings/

By default, it uses <kbd>Super</kbd>+ <kbd>X</kbd> to activate looking-glass but you can configure that keyboard shortcut.

---

Alternatively, you can use the [command to activate looking-glass](https://askubuntu.com/a/132359/25798) and [bind it to a specific keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73473/how-to-bind-custom-commands-to-keyboard-shortcuts).

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.lookingGlass.toggle();'
```

Answer (score 1):

**This answer probably doesn't solve the problem. See comments for details.**

You can run any command by setting a custom command. To be precise you won't set a keyboard shortcut to perform <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>`lg`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but to run the command `lg`.

This question explains how to do so: [How to bind custom commands to keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73473/how-to-bind-custom-commands-to-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question.  Technically, there is no `lg` command.  If there were, it'd be a cinch using the technique described.

Comment: If there's no `lg` command, then what does Alt-F2 execute?

Comment: `lg` is internal to Alt-F2.  When I say that it is not a command, I am referring to the fact that one cannot go to a plain terminal (i.e., console) and type `lg`.  There is no **command** file which executes in response to that entry on the command line.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't know that. I thought ALT+F2 just executes commands.

Comment: You *can* run `lg` from a plain terminal if you turn it on:  see http://askubuntu.com/a/118642/6161.