# How do I bind two different keyboard keys to the system mute function?

Tags: shortcut-keys

So, I want to bind two different keyboard keys to the system mute function. I go to `system settings > keyboard > shortcuts > sound and media` and find the Volume Mute setting and enter the second shortcut I want for it. However, this deletes the first shortcut. How can I bind two keys to this function?

Comment: Take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/73473/how-to-bind-custom-commands-to-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to do such a thing if you know the command for doing that function.
If you are using ALSA sound driver, the commands are :

amixer set Master mute` for muting the system

```
    "amixer set Master unmute" for unmuting the system  
    "amixer set Master toggle" for toggling volume.  
    "amixer set Master <vol>" to set volume level to <vol>
```

So, in the `Keyboard shortcut` option, click on `Add` and in the `Command` box, enter the functionality that you want.
Hope this helps.

Comment: None of those commands are working the same way as the existing command. Toggle will only turn the sound off but not back on. Mute just turns it off and unmute only turns it on.

Comment: someone filed this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/878986

Comment: How does the normal shortcut make it work then?