# How to change volume of pulseaudio playback apps and streams that aren't currently in use?

Tags: pulseaudio

I can change sound volumes with "*gnome-volume-control* ". But there are listed only playback-apps / -streams **that are currently in use**:

[image: screenshot]

In `~/.config/pulse/` I found `*-stream-volumes.tdb` and `*-device-volumes.tdb` that could be the configuration files but I am unable to read or edit these files.

Comment: Related: [Change application volume from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/588772/349837)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wrote a small tool that lets you set the volume of any client that pulseaudio remembers. Please see here:

https://github.com/rhaas80/pa_volume

for the repository. You will need the libpulse-dev package installed after which a simple "make" should build the tool. Please see its README.md file for usage.

```
dpkg -l | grep libpulse-dev # Check if installed
git clone git@github.com:rhaas80/pa_volume.git
cd pa_volume/
make
./pa_volume # list remembered PA clients
./pa_volume Program 30 # set to 30%
```

Comment: 6 years after asking the question, thank you for providing a working solution and sharing it here :)

Comment: You can also list clients with `pacmd list-clients` and kill them with `pacmd kill-client` ([`man pulse-cli-syntax`](https://www.mankier.com/5/pulse-cli-syntax)). To kill'em all: `for i in $(pacmd list-clients | grep index | grep -o "[0-9]*"); do pacmd kill-client $i; done`. Some will re-spawn, not sure why.

Answer (score 17):

Pulseaudio comes with a [command line interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/CLI/) ([`man pulse-cli-syntax`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/pulse-cli-syntax)) to control many settings.

We can either load the command line parser `pacmd` or we call commands directly in a terminal or script:

```
pacmd set-sink-volume <index> <volume>
pacmd set-source-volume <index> <volume>
```

controls the volume of a given sink where `<index>` is the sink index (listed with `pacmd list-sinks`) and `<volume>` is any value from 0 (= Mute) to 65536 = 100%.

The configurations files in `~/.config/pulse` (formerly `~/.pulse` which may still be active in an upgraded installation) are not meant to be read or edited in a default setting. We can however create a custom `default.pa` there to override settings in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

For 12.04 [earcandy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/earcandy) may be used for audio control. Sadly this application is not further developed and not available in later releases.

See also notes for [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line/14083#14083).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But I don't arrive. When I want adjust my amarok-volume for example, how do I do that? It is not listed in *list-sinks* or *list-sources*.

Comment: You can't do that by the command line interface. This is bound to output sinks.

Comment: I have already tested earcandy. It should do exactly the things I want to. But it is still not stable so I don't mark this question as solved.

Comment: @Lasall: no worries. We hope it will reach stable some time.

Answer (score 3):

To find your pulseaudio source sinks use following command:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

From this command you got the `running` and `idle` sinks. With their sink number. Using that index number you can control the sinks volume.

```
index: 128
    driver: <module-ladspa-sink.c>
    state: RUNNING
    sink: 0
    # ^ This is the sink number you want to find
```

You can use the following command to control particular sinks volume:

```
pactl set-sink-volume <index number> <volume in %>
```

For example:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 100%
```

Comment: Thank you to look at this old question. I only get one item in the sink list. My question was to control volume of different (not currently running) applications and not different audio interfaces.

Comment: It also doesn't answer the question, but you can see all currently running audio outputs with `pactl list sink-inputs`. If your program shows with id 108 in this list and you want to set it to 60% volume, use `pactl set-sink-input-volume 108 60%`. But the sound has to be running for it to work.

Comment: All I get for that: "No valid command specified."