# What component is responsible for tray and how to manipulate it using C++?

Tags: unity, gnome, c++, system-tray

My goal is to write a desktop gui application that will utilize these commands found in https://askubuntu.com/a/14083/18330

```
pacmd list-sinks to list name or index number of possible sinks

pacmd set-default-sink "SINKNAME" to set the default output sink

pacmd set-default-source "SOURCENAME" to set the default input

pacmd set-sink-volume index volume

pacmd set-source-volume index volume for volume control (0 = Mute, 65536 = 100%)
```

Then the application will have a tray icon that shows a list of sound devices that will be clickable to switch the sound device to that one. As they are clicked the sound volume will fade volume from 0 to the point the current system's volume (therefore I need access to the system volume as well.)

Unknowns:

- How to programmatically add a tray icon in c++
- How to make a drop down display when clicked on that tray icon and have it display items that are also clickable (much like how the mail icon displays Thunderbird)
- How to bind the click events to a c++ function that will run (in order to switch to that sound device I will have a c++ function ready.)

I just need some guidance about identifying the desktop component that I'm trying to manipulate and where to find the API documentation for it.

Notes:

- Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64
- Going to write this as an open source Node.js extension written in C++
- This is an [example of notifications written as a Node.js C++ extension](http://syskall.com/how-to-write-your-own-native-nodejs-extension/index.html/)

Comment: You might want to look at [`appindicator`](https://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/).

Comment: Thank you this was the information I was looking for. Please write an answer with examples to collect the bounty.

Comment: @Logan, for its doc's see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/42211/how-to-create-unity-indicators/234204#234204

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`libappindicator`](https://launchpad.net/libappindicator). It is responsible for putting the icon in the tray. The dropdown menu displayed by the indicator is a [`GtkMenu`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenu.html). The rest should be familiar if you worked with GTK+. Here is a minimal example.

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <libappindicator/app-indicator.h>

static void do_something(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
  //...
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  GtkWidget *menu = gtk_menu_new();
  GtkWidget *menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic("_This is a menu item");
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menuitem);
  g_signal_connect(menuitem, "activate", G_CALLBACK(do_something), NULL);

  /* the second parameter is the icon displayed */
  AppIndicator* ind = app_indicator_new("test", "indicator-messages-new", 
                     APP_INDICATOR_CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS);
  app_indicator_set_menu(ind, GTK_MENU(menu));
  gtk_main();
}
```

You compile it with the following. You'll need `libgtk2.0-dev` and `libappindicator-dev` packages.

```
$ gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 appindicator-0.1`
```

You'll figure out the rest. The easiest way is to check out other simple indicator applications.
For example, see the indicator from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/508230/313386).