# How can I force a gradual volume increase when any sound begins playback?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Scenario: I play loud music. I leave the computer for an hour. I come back, and resume the music, not remembering that the volume is set to "full".

Question: Is there something a can install, such as a pulseaudio plugin, that will allow me to specify:

Given that no audio has been played for `A` seconds, and the volume is above `B`, when audio begins playback, play it at volume `C`, gradually increasing volume back to `B` over a time of `D` seconds.

It would be strongly preferable if this could be done "globally", so it doesn't matter what the source of the sound is.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a music player that has such a feature.

To my knowledge, Clementine has this feature and it is available from the Ubuntu Software Center!

Comment: I might try clementine, but it would be even better if it could be set globally, (such as in pulseaudio), so it doesn't matter if I play music in the web browser (youtube music video or annoyingly loud ad), stream through spotify, or play local music with clementine.

Comment: Yep, I see your point ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to mute --- or lower --- the volume of your system on suspend (or resume), with a script. That means you have to crack it up manually after resume, but...

The command that set the volume should be something like:

```
pacmd set-sink-volume 0 20000
```

(`pacmd` is in the package `pulseaudio-utils`), where the `0`  is the default sink (sound output)  and the volume is a 16-bit number (from 0 to 65535); [more details in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/44723/16395). You have to experiment to find the command that works for your system.

To make that automatic at suspend/resume time, you can use the same technique explained in [this post:](https://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395) (I did not test it --- but it should work).

1. edit/create the file

   `gksudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/02_shush`
2. Put  this content in it:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   # set the volume low on suspend and resume. Change the command to suite your 
   # system. You can do that just in suspend OR resume or whatever; edit to your 
   # taste...

   case "$1" in
       resume|thaw)
           # this command(s) will be executed at resume time
           pacmd set-sink-volume 0 20000 > /dev/null
       ;;
       suspend|hibernate)
           # this command(s) will be executed before suspend
           pacmd set-sink-volume 0 20000 > /dev/null
       ;;
   esac
   ```
3. save and exit
4. make it executable:

   `sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/02_shush`

Comment: While that's an interesting idea, this assumes that machine hibernates, which it often doesn't in my case. I suppose I could write up the relevant script myself if I could ask pacmd for "is anything currently playing?", but I see no easy way to do that in `pacmd --help`.