# Change application volume from terminal

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Is there a way to change individual application volumes from the terminal? I found a way to change the [master](https://askubuntu.com/a/97945/100594) volume which is `amixer -D pulse sset Master 50%` but I would like to be able to change volumes for individual applications like is possible in `pavucontrol`. My usage would be for scripting.

Comment: Depends on the application. Look into `man <application>`

Comment: I don't want to change the in application volume, I want to change the pulseaudio volume level for any application. For example, skype, which has no runtime parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution hidden in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118512/how-to-reduce-the-volume-of-a-background-music-stream-when-a-different-audio-sou#comment187255_118524) on unix.stackexchange. Use `pactl list sink-inputs` to find your application's sink input number. Then use `pactl set-sink-input-volume [sink number] [volume percent]` to set the volume of your application.

Comment: This one is great. I can now fade out spotify with `for ((i=50;i<100;i+=1)); do; pactl set-sink-input-volume 28 $i%; sleep 0.05; done
` Just need to know how to get spotify sink in a more assuring way.

Comment: I had used this command to make a script to use the pedals from an old driving wheel to control music playback volume. I put the script up [here](https://gist.github.com/AkBKukU/b1c4ac785f92579bbba0). Check out the function `getSink` to see a way to do it in a script. Not that the second line in it uses the variable $SINKAPP. you can substitute your process name here.

Comment: Percentage no longer works. The max value is 0x10000. 

https://man.archlinux.org/man/pulse-cli-syntax.5.en#set_sink_volume_set_source_volume

Answer (score 1):

This function easily sets the volume of any app.

```bash
function pacmd-set-app-volume() {
  local player="$1"
  local volume="$2"
  firstPlayerSinkIndex="$(pacmd list-sink-inputs | awk '/index:|application.name |application.process.binary / {print $0};' | grep -iB 1 "$player" | awk '/index:/ {print $2; exit}')"  # get specific app sink
  [[ $firstPlayerSinkIndex ]] && pacmd set-sink-input-volume "$firstPlayerSinkIndex" "$((volume*65536/100))" # 100% → 65536
}
```

Could be added to `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`.

Usage:

```bash
pacmd-set-app-volume <loosly_app_name> <volume_percentage>
```

For e.g.:

```bash
pacmd-set-app-volume "MPV Media Player" 55  # Or "mpv" "75"
```