# Reduce internet utilization / disable automatic updates

Tags: internet, update-manager, automatic

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 on a connection that is limited to 200kb in speed. Normally this should be enough for my use, but Ubuntu is eating up the bandwidth).

When I run `pactl list sink-inputs` I see:
 No protocol specified
 xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
 Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
 Connection failure: Connection refused
 pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

One reason I think is the update manager. How can I disable that one to make no automatic package list updates anymore?

And which other standard functions might eat my bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

The illustrations at [Change application volume from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588772/change-application-volume-from-terminal) show in the screenshot under Other Settings & Scheduling Updates where you can alter the currency of collecting Update data. Disable *Automatically check for updates* and that will keep Update Manager from using bandwidth when not needed.

Comment: when i type this line : pactl list sink-inputs
this is what i get:
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

Comment: It's SOP here for questioners to post later findings by updating the original post by clicking on [edit] in grey under the tags.