# Lowering (→ducking) Spotify/… volume when somebody speaks on Zoom/Discord/…

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Do you have any idea how I could achieve aforementioned result with a reasonable amount of time and effort?

I've spent the past few hours researching and trying different approaches.

1. [module-role-ducking](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-role-ducking) seemed like a hot candidate. However, Discord does not specify the *media.role* property, so if I can't set that myself, it won't work. Even if adding the property did work, from my understanding, my music would be permanently ducked, as these voice chat clients don't pause/disconnect when nobody speaks.
2. I had a look at [spectrumyzer](https://github.com/HaCk3Dq/spectrumyzer) to see if I could intercept the sound output of the voice chat application, so I could do it all by myself (calculate voice chat volume, set music volume accordingly), but I'm not up to that task – I didn't find any helpful guides. This approach would, AFAIK, also involve creating another sink for just the voice chat application.
3. I could follow [this approach](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio) to pipe the voice chat audio to a custom script that does the things mentioned in **2**. But how would I process this raw audio information?
4. [pulseeffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects) is great, but it doesn't allow such interactions between applications
5. [Mumble VoIP](http://The%20actual%20ducking%20of%20other%20applications%20can%20be%20realized%20as) does the actual ducking-of-other-applications part, so that is absolutely doable.

Answer (score 1):

It's still in an early phase, but I made a working prototype of what I wanted!

https://github.com/NicoWeio/PulseDucking

I'll paste the *How it's done* section from my README, for future reference.

- For each currently running *trigger* application, a new thread is started.
- In each thread, `parec --monitor-stream=<STREAM_INDEX>` is called. It streams the raw audio of an application.
- By simply checking for `0x00`, silence/noise is detected.
- `pacmd set-sink-input-volume <SINK_INPUT_INDEX> <VOLUME>` is dispatched for all *ducking* applications.
- A loop ensures that new applications are taken into account as well.

So, as it turns out, detecting absolute silence in raw audio streams is not difficult at all, and getting the raw audio from a single application does not involve creating sinks/loopbacks/…, thanks to `parec --monitor-stream=<STREAM_INDEX>`.

---

Regarding 1., manually setting the stream's properties *is* possible using `pacmd update-sink-input-proplist <INDEX> media.role="…"`. I have yet to check whether *module-role-ducking* works, then.

Comment: I wrote [a little script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418749/349837) to manual ducking any process working as an input for a PulseAudio sink