# SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 USB on Lubuntu

Tags: server, alsa, lubuntu, soundcard

I'm having trouble after installing Lubuntu-desktop on top of a Ubuntu Server (64 bit).

The problem is that I cannot get my X-Fi external USB soundcard to work without horrible hacks, and even then at best it only works in some applications.

I can currently only play media in VLC media player using the following hack in my ~./asoundrc

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
ctl.!default {
    type hw           
    card 1
}
```

This works as expected, but not for many applications (which fail to launch, with a error message related to below (no mixer controls))

```
┌──────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.0.24.2 ────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro                      F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: USB Mixer                                     F2:  System information │
│ View: F3: Playback  F4: Capture  F5: All            F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item:                                               Esc: Exit               │
│                                                                             │
│                                                                             │
│                This sound device does not have any controls.                │
│                                                                             │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

What could I be missing? Some diagnostic information (any other information on request):

```
daniel@daniel-desktop:~$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
front:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Pro,DEV=1
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio #1
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Pro,DEV=1
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio #1
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Pro,DEV=1
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio #1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Pro,DEV=0
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Pro,DEV=1
    SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, USB Audio #1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Comment: What would happen if you pressed F6 on the Alsamixer? Is there any other cards?

Comment: @lkjoel There are 3 devices total, 2 of which are related to on board sound.

Comment: This situation is still unresolved :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solved my problem:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 0
defaults.ctl.card 1

pcm.upmix51 {
    type upmix
    slave.pcm "surround51"
    delay 15
    channels 6
}

pcm.!default "plug:upmix51"
```

Thanks go to Trilby on the [Archlinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139324) in his response to Fluxed.

Answer (score 1):

First, delete your hack or else you will run in more and more problems.

Watch this question to see how you can configure pulseaudio so the sound come out of the right card :
[How can I change the default audio device from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

I've actually gotten my X-Fi Titanium tamed rather well under Ubuntu. I've even written an article about it to help me remeber how to heck to fix it every time I break it, ubuntu updates or I re-install linux.

Good luck! :)

http://www.piotrkrzyzek.com/creative-x-fi-titanium-5-1-digital-surround-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.