# Creative Labs SB X-Fi not working on 11.04

Tags: 11.04, sound

Just did a clean install on my Dell XPS 710 H2C of 11.04 64 bit and now my Creative Labs PCI Express SB X-Fi Xtreme Gamer(SBO460-D) isn't working. Shows up in Preferences/Sound, hardware tab as SB-Fi with a full list of options in pull-down (setting for the selected device) and have tried them all and can only get front 2 speakers to work in some with horrible sound. Have tried finding the beta Linux drivers from Creative (XFiDrv_Linux_Public_US_1.00.tar.gz) but they seem to have been removed from all sites.

Has anyone gotten this card to work properly on 11.04 64 bit?

Anyone have suggestions for a decent replacement card?

> > Side note, when doing my clean install, I set up dual boot Win7 64 bit and it doesn't work properly on that OS either. Have gone through downloading new drivers from Creative, etc for that OS also to no avail. I don't have a problem with replacing the card but want to make sure I get a good, plug and play one that I don't have to fight with getting to work on both these operating systems...<<

Comment: you should have a look of this tip http://askubuntu.com/questions/45477/sb-x-fi-surround-5-1-usb-on-lubuntu