# Configuring HDMI Audio via command line

Tags: 10.04, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I'm looking for a way to configure HDMI audio output via the command line using pulseaudio. I was able to get it running by using pavucontrol and changing it in the configuration tab, but I need a way to automate the process. I haven't been able to find any documentation at all so far. The system is a lucid install.

Edit: From what I've found, I can use `pacmd set-card-profile` to do this. However, whenever I try, I get an error like the following (using the default profiles as defined in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf`)

```
# pacmd set-card-profile 0 hdmi-stereo
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> Failed to set card profile to 'hdmi-stereo'.

# pacmd set-card-profile 0 analog-stereo
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> Failed to set card profile to 'analog-stereo'.
```

Why can't I change these from command line when pavucontrol works to change them?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line/14083#14083) may help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was using the tool wrong. The correct way to do it was `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-audio`. You can get a list of avilable profile names by running `pacmd list-cards`.

Comment: the 2nd argument (0) is the index of the card (>>> 1 card(s) available.  index: 0). 
the 3rd argument (output:hdmi-audio) is the part before the second semicolon under "profiles:" (e.g. it's "output:hdmi-stereo" from the line output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400))

Comment: it's `pactl list cards` at least in `pulseaudio-utils 1:4.0-0ubuntu22`

Comment: @int_ua: `pactl list cards` and `pacmd list-cards` are both correct, the two tools use different syntax but provide most of the same functionality. In theory, the command to change the output profile could be `pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-audio` (or `... output:hdmi-stereo` or whatever), either will work.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install alsamixergui
```

Then run it (Alt+F2 or press super key):

```
alsamixergui
```

A window will open for sound cofiguration...

Comment: I'm not looking to edit mixer levels, I'm looking to configure the audio to use HDMI. I also said I'm not looking for a GUI tool, I need something that I can automate.

Comment: alsamixergui solution by @decent worked for me on Nvidia ION with 10.04 and now with 12.04, I just launched the command and **unmute** the channel **IEC 958 1**
now I have audio...

Answer (score -1):

I found a simpler way to do this - on the Hardware tab of the System Settings Sound control, right-click on the profile drop down and select 
Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo input from the list.

Comment: It needs to be from the command line.