# How can I change audio output to HDMI from command line?

Tags: command-line, sound, laptop, hdmi

**Backstory**

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line) suggests `pacmd list-sinks` and switching to a different sink with `pacmd set-default-sink "SINKNAME"`, but my laptop only appears to have 1 sink, so that didn't help me.

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63599/configuring-hdmi-audio-via-command-line) suggests `pacmd list-cards` which shows `hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort` right at the bottom of the output, and that looks right, but it  still says `Failure: No such entity` when I run `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-output` or `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-output-0`

Comment: might be better suited as an answer? To the threads that are linked.

Comment: Glad you found a solution and thank you for sharing. You should now write/copy your solution to an own answer and then [edit] your question to better fit to the Q & A format of this site. Thank you.

Comment: Hi James, I've added a community wiki answer below containing your solution. If you later decide you want to post your own answer please come and do that and then we can delete mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

The OP posted the solution [in his question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/539768/revisions):

> **While writing this I found the solution:**
>
> This command makes it easier to see what my actual output options are:
>
> ```
> pacmd list-cards | grep output\:
> ```
>
> That way of looking at the output of `pacmd list-cards` made me
>   realize that the actual wording for my output is not
>   `output:hdmi-output` but instead `output:hdmi-stereo`
>
> **This command is what worked for me:**
>
> ```
> pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
> ```
>
> This is how I switched back to my laptop's internal speakers:
>
> ```
> pactl set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo
> ```
>
> This is how I changed the volume via command line:
>
> ```
> amixer -D pulse sset Master 50%
> ```
>
> This is just a smiley face:
>
> ```
> :)
> ```

Comment: I have two cards. So I changed the 0 to 1 to change the default to analog stereo.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to specify, that if you have many different outputs, you can find all with

```
pactl list
```

For other HDMI output the command is

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo-extra1
```

PS: It's for the HDMI-2 output