# Audio over HDMI stopped working after running Software Updater today

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

Radeon HD4200 connected via HDMI to a TV, machine has been running Ubuntu 18.04 for several months with sound working perfectly. Ran Updater today, sound stopped working.

Pulseaudio shows Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output as Unplugged. Edited grub to include the radeon.audio=1 piece as advised elsewhere when this happens, and rebooted. No bueno.

Other instructions I found elsewhere (pacmd set-card-profile, Ctrl/Alt/F1 to F7) seem to make no difference. Machine has been rebooted multiple times and cable switched out, to no avail.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change audio output to HDMI from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539768/how-can-i-change-audio-output-to-hdmi-from-command-line)