# How to set a shortcut that alternate it's function conditionally?

Tags: gnome, sound, shortcut-keys, hdmi, customization

I want to set a unique hotkey to be able to alternate the system sound between analog and HDMI outputs. How can I do this?

This behavior could be observed in `play` shortcut (from `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys`) that play and pause the media alternatively.

> I could find answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/541043/689894) that the command to set the sound-output is `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:[card-profile]`

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/28588147 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/27857085 help. (I searched the 'net for *bash* *toggle*.)

Comment: You need to find a way to read the current status. This may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65246/change-pulseaudio-input-output-from-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, reading the topics that [DK Bose](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose) and [vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium) suggested and having done some more research to learning about bash script and [Linux PulseAudio sound server](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pulseaudio.1.html), I came up with one solution:

We need to save the following script in a file (preferably in `/usr/local/bin/`, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/465162/689894)), mark it as executable (by run `chmod +x` over it) and then assigned it to a keyboard shortcut (optionally as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/826328/689894)).

```
#!/bin/bash
sound_output=$(pacmd list-cards | grep "active")

if [[ $sound_output = *"analog-stereo"* ]]; then
  sound_output=hdmi-stereo
else
  sound_output=analog-stereo
fi

pactl set-card-profile 0 output:"$sound_output"
echo -e "PulseAudio sound server output set to $sound_output"
```

> Explaning:
>
> - `#!/bin/bash` ensures that the interpreter for this script is bash, enabling extended syntax such as [[ ]].
> - As cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28588354/2989289), the syntax `$( )` is "command substitution". This runs a command and use it's output to compose the line action. This way we save the
>     return of `pacmd list-cards | grep "active"` in `sound_output`
>     variable.
> - As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229606/2989289), the use of `*` in the condition turn it into a substring check.
> - As answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/541043/689894), `pactl set-card-profile 0 output: [card-profile]` is the command to switch the sound server output, as
>     wished.