# Recovering sound output options via command line

Tags: 18.04, gnome, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

> After the resolution of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1168268/689894), I'm using the [following
>   script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169006/689894) to alternate my computer sound-output through a keyboard
>   shortcut

```
#!/bin/bash
sound_output=$(pacmd list-cards | grep "active")

if [[ $sound_output = *"analog-stereo"* ]]; then
  sound_output=hdmi-stereo
else
  sound_output=analog-stereo
fi

pactl set-card-profile 0 output:"$sound_output"
echo -e "PulseAudio sound server output set to $sound_output"
```

However, while I have a device wire-connected in headphone output port there's a third output option in *system settings sound menu* that also use an `analog-stereo` profile.

[image: system settings sound menu]

Which other strategy could I use to find out the available outputs options and circle through them?

Comment: What is the output of `pacmd list-cards`?

Comment: You want to change the port, not the profile. See [Change default port for PulseAudio (line out, not headphones)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/175930).