# How do I set a pulseaudio card profile persistently across reboots

Tags: sound, configuration, pulseaudio

I'm trying to set up pulseaudio's card profiles, and I've gotten profile switching to work using `pactl set-card-profile`, but so far when the machine reboots, the audio profile reverts back to the default of `output:analog-stereo` instead of remaining on HDMI. How can I set the profile in a way that persists across reboots?

Answer (score 10):

To make default settings for the pulseaudio daemon we can edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (as root) to give a default source or sink in the last section by uncommenting the corresponding lines and give in the name of our output sink and input source:

```
### Make some devices default
set-default-sink <name_of_sink>
set-default-source <name_of_source>
```

In case your sound card needs a specific profile we can also add the follwing line:

```
set-card-profile <cardindex> <profilename>
```

**Please make a backup of this file before editing to be able to restore the default setting.**

In case you are unsure what name your sink has you can issue the following command in a terminal to list all sinks presently active:

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

To test if the sink is correct we can issue

```
pacmd set-default-sink <nameofsink>
```

in a terminal before we change the default.pa. Open *Audio Settings* to see the effect (but this will not actually change the sink with default settings - see [this answer!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line/14083#14083))

Comment: I'm not using sink setting (as far as I know). I'm changing profiles by using `pactl set-card-profile`. Is this still done the same way? How do I find out what sinks get put in the config file?

Comment: Usually there will be an audio sink for the HDMI port listed on `pacmd list-sinks` (e.g. `<alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1>` this may be different on your hardware!) that you can use for your default.pa.

Comment: **Another note:** you should test your command using `pacmd set-default-sink <nameofsink>` in a terminal to see if it does what you want.

Comment: In all cases that I've seen so far, I only ever have one sink in the list-sinks output. What details the sink states change based on what card profile I have enabled. If I try to use set-default-sink, I get "Sink <name> does not exist"

Comment: In this case you can add your `set-card-profile <card-index> <profilename>` to the default.pa

Comment: @Takkat: IDK if this knowledge is useful, but you can test with **pactl** instead of **pacmd** if so desired. The command-line arguments are the same.

Comment: The `pacmd info` output speaks of `sink input(s)` and `source output(s)` but the names of the sinks listed by `pacmd list-sinks` all include the string *output* - so much for consistency in terminology.

Comment: Instead of hacking `/etc/pulse/default.pa` directly, you can drop an extra script under `/etc/pulse/default.pa.d`.