Can you save Pulse Audio settings to a configuration file that can be loaded from the GUI?
Can one make pulse audio volume control settings or configurations saveable and loadable from the GUI? This would eliminate much wasted time with faffing with every single setting to restore them to a working condition everytime you reboot.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a feature request, not a question.

You should describe detailed what your problem is, there might be a solution for your problems. but without relevant details we can't help much.

The problem is that after spending a lot of time adjusting my audio settings, they are all lost after reboot.   Is the lack of persistence considered a helpful feature?

Either edit your question or ask a new question with relevant details such as Ubuntu version. Your statement in your comment above is not sufficient.

The same problem was reported 13 years ago, in form of a question.  No reasonable solutions have been arrived at since then. https://askubuntu.com/questions/69820/how-do-i-set-a-pulseaudio-card-profile-persistently-across-reboots

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
