# Change default sound device

Tags: sound, 13.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 my sound stopped working. I eventually figured out that Ubuntu had selected the HDMI sound device instead of my analogue speakers. I switched to the correct device and everything worked fine until I rebooted. I now have to select the correct device every time I boot Ubuntu. How do I set my speakers as the default device?

Edit: Since i upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 Ubuntu now selects the onboard sound device by default so I no longer have this problem.

Comment: Would you like a solution for this? What device are you trying to make the default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the default audio device from command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line)

Comment: This question is not a duplication of that post. Maybe it would be more appropriate for the title to be "Change default default sound device" (the word default is intentionally used twice). Hope that clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 37):

Run:

```
$ pacmd list-cards
```

To display the index of your cards.  For example, my pci sound card is at index 2. The sound profile for analogue output (again as an example) is called "output:analog-stereo".

Then:

```
$ pacmd set-card-profile 2 output:analog-stereo
```

To set this as the output (give it a try).
To make it permanent, edit /etc/pulse/default.pa and add:

```
set-card-profile 2  output:analog-stereo
set-default-sink 2
```

Restart pulseaudio or reboot to check persistence.

If you want to also set mic(input) defaults

```
set-card-profile 2  output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
set-default-sink 2
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the only way to solve my problem, having every sound muted after ALSA & JACKD installation...

Comment: Works like a charm on 16.04. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Voting this up because it helped save a very similar issue in Debian. Thank you very much.

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 17.10. I was first confused because `pacmd list-cards` only listed one card so I thought I could not switch. I want to switch from my laptop speakers to hdmi. This is the same card for me, just another output (`analog-stereo` vs. `hdmi-stereo`).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!Struggled a lot to fix this...

Comment: Great solution. Thank you very much. This made it possible for me to switch sound-profiles and therefore devices (headphones, digital-spdif) via a keystroke in LXDE. This in combination with keystrokes for display switching makes multimedia on Linux so much more enjoyable than on Windows.

Comment: Helpful on my system too (MATE 18.04).

Answer (score 3):

On the Dash, search for **Multimedia Systems Selector**.

Open it and in its `Audio` tab you can select the default audio Input and Output devices.

[image]

This application is installed by default in Ubuntu Installation. But if you haven`t this somehow can install by

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-media
```

If it is not shown in the Dash, run:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/gstreamer-properties.desktop
```

In the resulting text file, go to the line starts with `NoDisplay=`. Change the `NoDisplay=true` to `NoDisplay=false`

Comment: Thanks for the thourough response, unfortunately this didn't work. It would seem like this is the perfect solution but Ubuntu seems to ignore these preferences and continues to select the HDMI sound device on startup.

Comment: Same for me. Did you fix it @OpenTangent?

Comment: No, sorry. I just use Suspend now instead of Shut Down. I still need to correct it when i restart.

Comment: I found a solution to this that works for me, in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for Ubuntu 16.04 was to create a script that listens when screen unlocks instead of script that listens to when system wakeups because it seems not all services are available at the instant that system wakes up. I couldn't get pulseaudio to switch to HDMI sound with a wakeup script but have successfully fixed it using the unlock listening script:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6'" | \
(
  while true; do
    read X
    if echo $X | grep "desktop-lock" &> /dev/null; then
        echo "screen locked"
    elif echo $X | grep "desktop-unlock" &> /dev/null; then
      /usr/bin/pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo
    fi
  done
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a newer 3.x gnome, show your launcher (default windows key) type settings -> sound.  Select a different default, close the window.

[image: Picture of the select sound window]

Answer (score 1):

There's also an [Audio Output Switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/751/audio-output-switcher/) GNOME extension, which provides quick access:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default by ordering the sound cards in ALSA with `slots=`.

Find the driver module names for the sound cards you want to use by inspecting`lsmod`'s output with: `lsmod | grep -P '^snd[_]?[A-z]*'` or just `lsmod`. For e.g. my Creative X-FI Xtreme Gamer is `snd_ctxfi`, my on-board is `snd_hda_intel` and my USB webcam is `snd_usb_audio`.

Now open up in a text editor or nano your corresponding ALSA config file e.g. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and at the bottom add something of the following in order of precedence (the first declaration becomes default):

`options snd slots=snd_ctxfi,snd_hda_audio,snd_usb_audio` then to save just `CTRL+o+enter` & `CTRL+x`. Restart and you may be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you to user224082 for your solution which helped me discover which device I needed.

To find which ALSA device you need:

1. Using Multimedia Systems Selector, choose **ALSA — Advanced Linux Sound 
   Architecture** for *Plugin*
2. Test the different options under *Device* until the desired speaker is
   selected
3. Make a note of the `device=` value in the Pipeline box. Mine was `"hw:0,4"`

Once you know which device you need, set it as the default:

Edit default.pa by typing `sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa`

At the very bottom of the file, add:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink sink_name=spkr device=hw:0,4
set-default-sink spkr
```

replacing the `device=` value with your device.