# How can I change the default audio device port?

Tags: sound

I want to set my audio device:hdmi/display port 4 to be the default one. I'm on ubuntu 14.04lts 64bits with mate desktop. Right now I have to manually change it every time I reboot my pc.

Now to be clear: my device is *already* the default one and working just fine .. its just not the right *port* by default.

Here is the info on my device:

```
>> 1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 20
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-surround-extra3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9050
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100% 2: 100% 3: 100% 4: 100% 5:   0%
            0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB 2: 0.00 dB 3: 0.00 dB 4: 0.00 dB 5: -inf dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 21
    sample spec: s16le 6ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
                 Surround 5.1
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 113.33 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    module: 5
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 3"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 3"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "9"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf3080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0e0b"
        device.string = "hdmi:0,3"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65280"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32640"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-surround-extra3"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU 41 HDMI/DP"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de0041,10438422,00100100"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "DENON-AVAMP
 "
    active port: <hdmi-output-3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page worked for me: [Change default sound device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398030/change-default-sound-device)

Comment: This is not really an *answer* but as it has been accepted by the OP as *the answer that has solved this issue* I will close the question as a Duplicate that points towards this linked question...