# No sound on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have a Dell xps13 that previously had 14.04 and the sound worked fine. I recently installed 18.04 and now I have no sound through either my speakers or headphones. The sound settings look like this: 
[image]
(Note that there is no 'Test Sound' button. )

[Edit] I've already tried many of the fixes I've found on AskUbuntu, including:

- `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` (nothing changes)
- I've tried reinstalling `alsa` and `pulseaudio`. [/Edit]

I'm now following the Ubuntu [troubleshooting guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) for sound.

At step 3, entering `wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh` yields the output: https://pastebin.com/raw/44UDnp63

Running the code in step 4 yields https://pastebin.com/raw/YinifjQC

I've checked with `pavucontrol` to make sure that nothing is muted. This is what the panel looks like:

[image]

(The lower bar indicates that sound is playing, but I don't hear anything out of the speakers/headphones.)

Please help!

---

**Edit**:

As per Muntaha's suggestion, I tried

> mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse

and restarted. Now I have only dummy output listed:

[image]

The standard answer online to fix the 'dummy output' problem is to run `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` but this does nothing. Trying to figure out what to do now...

---

**Further edit**:

As per the solution to this question ["Dummy Output" No sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04):

> In the end, I rebooted into the bios and disabled the built-in audio, applied those changes, rebooted to Ubuntu, then rebooted again into the bios to re-enable the audio. Once back into Ubuntu after that, everything seemed to work great!

This also worked for me!

Comment: You can try this command: `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`

Comment: I've tried that already (see edits). Have any other ideas?

Comment: why 18.04 specifically? like why not 19.04 (in exatly 7 days) or 18.10? let's try running you through some solutions for 18.04, if you're dead set on it : you could update the system if you haven't already with `sudo apt full-upgrade -y` you can also upgrade the kernel `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu -y && sudo ukuu`.

Comment: I'd like to know if the sound works via HDMI attached. If so, maybe there is one switch to activate/deactivate the internal speakers. Maybe `alsamixer` on the console/terminal could help to try the possible switches.

Comment: same problem, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134314/dummy-output-in-ubuntu-16-04-after-fresh-install

Comment: @LupusE It still does not work through HDMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your home directory and then go to the hidden config directory. Rename the directory named pulse here:

> mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse

Now reboot your system. The pulse directory should be created afresh and you should have sound.

Comment: I did this, then all I saw was a dummy output. Then I used the solution in thie post https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04. Namely, I rebooted into BIOS to disable all audio, then reboot and reenable all audio. Now I've got sound!

Comment: well i'm glad to know it worked.. enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution for you it the above one didn't work for you...

Open the **terminal** and **edit speech-dispatcher file** by using the following command:

> sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher

In here, change **RUN=yes** to **RUN=no**

Reboot and enjoy the sound

Comment: RUN was already set to no.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto#Playing_with_probe_mask seems to work for me; I've added the following two lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
```

... and rebooted (after trying various other tips so YMMV).

Answer (score 0):

What I found was to remove the `timidity-deamon`:

```
sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
```

Thanks to Aaro Alhainen for [his post](https://aaroalhainen.medium.com/how-i-fixed-my-ubuntu-20-04-no-audio-dummy-output-issue-eaa525838e0d).

You can read about [timidity-deamon](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/timidity-daemon).

Comment: Please do not send the same answer to different questions.