# "Dummy Output" in Ubuntu 16.04 after fresh install

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

The history is very long.

1. HP brand desktops bought with windows 10
2. Installed ubuntu 16.04, worked perfectly. No sound problem
3. Bought a new monitor.
4. Can't rotate the screen.
5. Install Nvidia graphics driver.
6. Now I can change rotation from Nvidia controller.
7. Worked fine at this moment.
8. Went to windows for some work.
9. Windows updated, restarted.
10. Ubuntu 16.04 got login loop.
11. Try almost all the solution in the net. Doesn't work.
12. Make a new bootable pen drive using rofus of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
13. Can't install 18.04LTS. Basically at this point the boot loader can't be installed. Showed fatal error.
14. Collect a similar bootable pen drive (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) from a friend.  Now this time it installs (successfully installed bootloader), but yet again login loop.
15. Again make a bootable pendrive(18.04LTS) using "Universal-USB-Installer", this time There are some error related to kernel.
16. Finally made a 16.04LTS bootable pen drive with "Universal-USB-Installer", it successfully installs the OS but can't install the bootloader. Surprisingly this time when I restated the PC, it booted into 16.04 LTS but The wallpaper is Ubuntu 18.04LTS's wallpaper. Checked the OS by restarting and try to see if some files can be saved or not, but everything is ok.
17. OS is now running perfectly but there is no SOUND. 
    Some POST I've already followed,

command

```
alsamixer
```

output

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

```
uname -a
```

output

```
4.18.0-15-generic
```

Note that I had `4.18.0-15-generic` as kernel. At that time 
"sudo apt-get install linux-image-`uname -r`"  was not working. I had to download the deb from https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/cosmic/main/proposed/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic

and install it.

1.

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

output:

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
```

2. ```
   sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
   sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove

   sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
   sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
   load-module module-switch-on-port-available
   sudo init 6
   ```
  3.

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

3. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   echo options snd-hda-intel model=auto | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

output

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

4. Stop Sound option in bios, reboot to ubuntu and again start sound option in bios and reboot to ubuntu.
5. try to change kernel from the advance options in ubuntu grub.

some image of sound setings and pulseaudio volume control. In pulse audio volume controle it is showing that audio is running in chrome and `dummy output` driver is getting that audio.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have also tried this, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

While starting the ubuntu there is status screen comes for 1-3 second,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple recovery to the OS of the most recent available should solve the dummy output problem, if it does, then run command "sudo update-grub". This should be done every time
settings or software are changed.

Also sounds like you have a bootloader problem. Windows will damage this if it gets the opportunity. It can be repaired with Boot repair image cd you can make free of charge from Ubuntu. Keep the bootloader out of Windows access, and on any reinstall, always install Windows first before Ubuntu. That keeps the bootloader under Ubuntu control. Then run boot repair and this will usually repair dual boot problems in a few minutes or less. Once this is working again, then run the update-grub commend again to complete.

Comment: It doesn't work.